# Remove dropdown (select) button from dropdown menus?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I was wondering if there is a way to remove the dropdown (`<select>`) button (the little arrow) from the dropdown menu? I want to create a item list, but without the arrow.

- Steve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this, especially cross-browser.  You can replace the `<select>` elements entirely with another control, but you can't modify how a `<select>` renders...not in the way you want at least.

[Here](http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/jquery_ui_selectmenu_an_aria_accessible_plugin_for_styling_a_html_select/) are a [few](http://ajax.phpmagazine.net/2007/07/select_box_replacement_with_jq.html) [examples](http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/branches/labs/selectmenu/index.html) of [replacements](http://www.ajaxupdates.com/jquery-select-box/).

Comment: Also, check out this article: http://tutorialzine.com/2010/11/better-select-jquery-css3/

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are looking for something more like this:

```
<html>
  <body>

  <select size=1>
    <option>Volvo</option>
    <option>Saab</option>
    <option>Mercedes</option>
    <option>Audi</option>
  </select>

  </body>
</html>
```

This will create a select list of items one item tall.  On some browsers there will still be an empty scrollbar, but it will get rid of the drop down arrow. As long as the size of the select tag is set then the arrow will not appear.

There are more options on select lists here: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp

Answer (score 0):

[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5912791/how-to-remove-the-arrow-from-a-select-tag-in-firefox/#18317228) from [João Cunha](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1411163/joao-cunha) is working wonders for me

**pure CSS!**

I added a bit of code to extend the browser support, see [my answer in that question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20238882/1343595) or below:

```
select {
    /*for firefox*/
    -moz-appearance: none;
    /*for chrome*/
    -webkit-appearance:none;
    text-indent: 0.01px;
    text-overflow: '';
}
/*for IE10*/
select::-ms-expand {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this code:

```
select {
   -webkit-appearance: none;
   background-color: #FFF;
   border: medium none;
   color: #555555;
   font-family: inherit;
   outline: medium none;
   overflow: hidden;
   padding: 0;
   text-overflow: ellipsis;
   white-space: nowrap;
   width: 10em;
   height: 1em;
}
```

itz work for me. Just try it.