# css class to make html select look like span

Tags: jquery, css, drop-down-menu, html

I am trying to make select look like span based on some condition. i have following css class that works fine with input boxes but it doesnt work with dropdown. Any guidance how can i make the select look like span rather than replacing select with span?

jQuery function

```
function makeReadOnly(context) {
   $('input, select', context).each(function() {
   $(this).addClass('readOnlyInput');
   });​
}
```

CSS

```
.readOnlyInput
{
   border-width: 0;
   background-color: Transparent;
   text-align: right;
}
```

Comment: It's not that easy to style a select :P You may need a jQuery plugin to change select's appearance or some [tricky css](http://bavotasan.com/2011/style-select-box-using-only-css/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just replace the `select` with a `span`. That's the standard way of doing what you're trying to do, and I think you'll have a lot of difficulty making a `select` look like anything other than a `select` since it's a system control. `select` elements don't even look the same on different browsers/operating systems, because as a web developer you don't have the ability to restyle it.

Even your standard restyled combo boxes and such, like the many jQuery plugins available out there, hide the original `select` and replace it with a series of `div`s and such.

Answer (score 2):

Trying to style SELECTs is a dead end.
Replacing SELECTs upon pageload with lists that look and behave just like SELECTs? Totally doable: http://filamentgroup.com/lab/jquery_ui_selectmenu_an_aria_accessible_plugin_for_styling_a_html_select/

Always keep accessibility in mind, though.

Answer (score 0):

How about making it `disabled`:

```
function makeReadOnly(context) {
   $('input, select', context).each(function() {
      $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
   });​
}
```

***W3C Recommendation:***

> In contexts where user input is either undesirable or irrelevant, it
>   is important to be able to disable a control or render it read-only.
>   For example, one may want to disable a form's submit button until the
>   user has entered some required data. Similarly, an author may want to
>   include a piece of read-only text that must be submitted as a value
>   along with the form. The following sections describe disabled and
>   read-only controls.

http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.12

Comment: disabled makes them look like engraved. i want them to appear like normal span. also it doesnt get rid of dropdown button

Comment: @Asdfg you can style it to a *certain* extent. Other than that you will need to hide the `select` and display some other `element` like a `span` with the appropriate value.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. There is no style available to remove the arrow that you see in the drop down.

You are going to replace the drop down with a span if you want it to look like a span. All other are hacks are not going to be browser compatible or simply complicating it.

One such method to hide arrow [How to remove the arrow from a select element in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5912791/how-to-remove-the-arrow-from-a-select-tag-in-firefox)

Answer (score 0):

Not a viable solution but you should set the background-color to black for a select box to make it look like a span tag because you can not change the arrow color to something else.

```
background-color: black;
```