# Styling a select element in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, styles

Im trying to style a `<select>` in firefox. In chrome I made it with:

```
-webkit-appearance: none;
background: #eeeeee url("../img/select-arrow.jpg") no-repeat center right;
```

But on firefox I cant seem to be able to get the same result with

```
-moz-appearance: none;
background: #eeeeee url("../img/select-arrow.jpg") no-repeat center right;
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Since Firefox 35, "`-moz-appearance:none`" that you already wrote in your code, finally remove arrow button as desired.

It was a [**bug**](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=649849) solved since that version.

Answer (score 8):

Looks like this is bug on Firefox: -moz-appearance:none with select element.
See this bug report for more information: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=649849

Comment: I'm not sure it's a 'bug' so much.  With `-moz-appearance: none` a select is basically implemented via a component-like anonymous DOM, which the page just can't style.

Comment: Can't believe this bug hasn't been fixed yet.

Comment: Can't believe this bug hasn't been fixed yet... :)

Comment: It is a bug indeed, but there is a CSS only fix for it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5912791/how-to-remove-the-arrow-from-a-select-tag-in-firefox

Comment: Can't believe this bug hasn't been fixed yet.

Comment: Can't believe this bug hasn't been fixed yet.

Comment: Is fixed in Firefox 35

Comment: I can't believe it's not butter!

Answer (score 4):

Exact duplicate as this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18317228/1411163

Same answer:

Just figured out how to remove the select arrow from Firefox. The trick is to use a mix of -prefix-appearance, text-indent and text-overflow. It is pure CSS and requires no extra markup.

```
select {
    -moz-appearance: none;
    text-indent: 0.01px;
    text-overflow: '';
}
```

Tested on Windows 8, Ubuntu and Mac, latest versions of Firefox.

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/joaocunha/RUEbp/1/

More on the subject: https://gist.github.com/joaocunha/6273016

Comment: Great find João! I've updated my JSFiddle to implement your trick as well as the Webkit and IE one to form a really nice Pure CSS cross-browser solution.

Answer (score 3):

EDIT[2]: Since @joão-cunha's [awesome trick](https://gist.github.com/joaocunha/6273016) stopped working in FF30, see this new workaround: http://jsfiddle.net/sstur/2EZ9f/ (based on @keska's display:flex fix and some text-shadow magic)

EDIT: This can be done using pure CSS, as demonstrated here: http://jsfiddle.net/sstur/fm5Jt/

This will style it in Chrome, Firefox, IE10+ and will gracefully degrade in old IE and other legacy browsers. It uses various vendor-specific workarounds including `-webkit-appearance: none` as you mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use different value for `-moz-appearance` property. For example 
`-moz-appearance: toolbox;` works fine for me.

Full list of values can be found here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-moz-appearance

Answer (score 1):

Try below code sample:

```
<h2>CSS-only custom-styled selects v8</h2>

    <p><Strong>How this works:</strong> This styles a native select consistently cross-platform with only minimal CSS. The native select is then styled so it is essentially invisible (no appearance, border, bg) leaving only the select's text visible. There is a wrapper around the select that has the majority of the button styles (gradient, shadow, border, etc.). We then add the custom arrow via a pseudo element to the right. </p>


    <label>Native select</label>
    <select>
      <option>Apples</option>
      <option>Bananas</option>
      <option>Grapes</option>
      <option>Oranges</option>
      <option selected>A very long option name to test wrapping</option>
    </select>


    <label class="wrapper">This label wraps the select
      <div class="button custom-select ff-hack">
        <select>
          <option>Apples</option>
          <option>Bananas</option>
          <option>Grapes</option>
          <option>Oranges</option>
          <option>A very long option name to test wrapping</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </label>

    <label class="wrapper" for="states">This label is stacked above the select</label>
    <div class="button custom-select">
      <select id="states">
        <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
        <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
        <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
        <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
        <option value="CA">California</option>
        <option value="CO">Colorado</option>
        <option value="CT">Connecticut</option>
        <option value="DE">Delaware</option>
        <option value="FL">Florida</option>
        <option value="GA">Georgia</option>
        <option value="HI">Hawaii</option>
        <option value="ID">Idaho</option>
        <option value="IL">Illinois</option>
        <option value="IN">Indiana</option>
        <option value="IA">Iowa</option>
        <option value="KS">Kansas</option>
        <option value="KY">Kentucky</option>
        <option value="LA">Louisiana</option>
        <option value="ME">Maine</option>
        <option value="MD">Maryland</option>
        <option value="MA">Massachusetts</option>
        <option value="MI">Michigan</option>
        <option value="MN">Minnesota</option>
        <option value="MS">Mississippi</option>
        <option value="MO">Missouri</option>
        <option value="MT">Montana</option>
        <option value="NE">Nebraska</option>
        <option value="NV">Nevada</option>
        <option value="NH">New Hampshire</option>
        <option value="NJ">New Jersey</option>
        <option value="NM">New Mexico</option>
        <option value="NY">New York</option>
        <option value="NC">North Carolina</option>
        <option value="ND">North Dakota</option>
        <option value="OH">Ohio</option>
        <option value="OK">Oklahoma</option>
        <option value="OR">Oregon</option>
        <option value="PA">Pennsylvania</option>
        <option value="RI">Rhode Island</option>
        <option value="SC">South Carolina</option>
        <option value="SD">South Dakota</option>
        <option value="TN">Tennessee</option>
        <option value="TX">Texas</option>
        <option value="UT">Utah</option>
        <option value="VT">Vermont</option>
        <option value="VA">Virginia</option>
        <option value="WA">Washington</option>
        <option value="WV">West Virginia</option>
        <option value="WI">Wisconsin</option>
        <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <div style="width:50%; min-width:10em;">
      <label class="wrapper">In 50% wide container
        <div class="button custom-select">
          <select>
            <option>Apples</option>
            <option>Bananas</option>
            <option>Grapes</option>
            <option>Oranges</option>
            <option>A very long option name to test wrapping and visual collisions</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </label>
    </div>

    <label>Text input:
      <input type="text" placeholder="I'm a placeholder">
    </label>

    <h4><a href="https://twitter.com/toddmparker">Todd Parker</a> - <a href="http://www.filamentgroup.com">Filament Group Inc.</a></h4>

    <h4>Taken From <a href="http://jsbin.com/yaruh/edit?html,output">Todd Parker's JSBIN</a></h4>
    <h4>Taken From <a href="https://gist.github.com/joaocunha/6273016">Joaocunha's Gist</a></h4>

    <p><strong>Joaocunha's Update:</strong> <a href="https://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/rev/161e4dbfff7d">Thu Oct 02, 2014</a><br>
      Mozilla to address this issue (Target: v.35)<br>
      <i>Bug 649849, part 1 - Make -moz-appearance:none on a combobox remove the dropdown button (for WebKit compat). r=roc</i></p>


    <h2>Confirmed to work in the following browsers</h2>
    <p>This technique seems to be functional everywhere since we're still leaving the native select in place. Worst case, the native select styling and the custom arrow will both show up but in all popular platforms, this looks very good and consistent. One minor caveat: setting the select to 110% means the menu may open up a bit wider than expected in Firefox. <a href="http://postimg.org/image/g7i0o6mr1/">Visual Test results</a></p>

    <h3>Custom select styled consistently</h3>
    <ul>
      <li>iOS 4/5/6/7/8 - looks good, iOS3 even works fine but isn't quite as pretty</li>
      <li>Android 2.2/2.3 (Browser) - looks good</li>
      <li>Android 4.0/4.1/4.2 (Browser) - looks good</li>
      <li>Android 4.0/4.1/4.2/4.3/4.4 (Chrome) - looks good</li>
      <li>WP8 - looks good</li>
      <li>Kindle Fire 2/HD - looks good</li>
      <li>IE 10/11 - looks good</li>
      <li>Safari 5 - looks good</li>
      <li>Chrome 22-35 - looks good</li>
      <li>Opera 15-22 - looks good</li>
    </ul>

    <h3>Custom select with minor visual issues</h3>
    <ul>
      <li>iOS3 even works fine but isn't quite as pretty</li>
      <li>Firefox (all versions) - select menu when open is wider then it needs to be (by ~50px) to clip off the native arrow. Note that the select text can run under the arrow, no solution found for that.</li>
      <li>Opera Mini - alignment of text and arrows is a bit off but it works</li>
      <li>Opera Mobile - custom and native arrows both appear</li>
      <li>Nokia Asha - Long options can break outside the box</li>
    </ul>

    <h3>Native select</h3>

    <ul>
      <li>WP 7.5-7.8 - native select</li>
      <li>IE 6/7/8/9 - native select</li>
      <li>Opera pre-14 - native select</li>
    </ul>
```

And styles:

```
/* Some basic page styles */
    body {
      background-color: #fff;
      font-family: helvetica, sans-serif;
      margin: 4% 10%
    }

    /* Label styles: style as needed */
    label {
      display:block;
      margin-top:2em;
      font-size: 0.9em;
      color:#777;
    }

    /* Container used for styling the custom select, the buttom class below adds the bg gradient, corners, etc. */
    .custom-select {
      position: relative;
      display:block;
      margin-top:0.5em;
      padding:0;
    }

    /* These are the "theme" styles for our button applied via separate button class, style as you like */
    .button {
      border: 1px solid #bbb;
      border-radius: .3em;
      box-shadow: 0 1px 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,.04);
      background: #f3f3f3; /* Old browsers */
      background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%, #e5e5e5 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
      background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#ffffff), color-stop(100%,#e5e5e5)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
      background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%,#e5e5e5 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
      background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%,#e5e5e5 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
      background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%,#e5e5e5 100%); /* IE10+ */
      background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffffff 0%,#e5e5e5 100%); /* W3C */
    }

    /* This is the native select, we're making everything but the text invisible so we can see the button styles in the wrapper */
    .custom-select select {
      width:100%;
      margin:0;
      background:none;
      border: 1px solid transparent;
      outline: none;
      /* Prefixed box-sizing rules necessary for older browsers */
      -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
      -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      /* Remove select styling */
      appearance: none;
      -webkit-appearance: none;
      /* Font size must the 16px or larger to prevent iOS page zoom on focus */
      font-size:16px;
      /* General select styles: change as needed */
      font-family: helvetica, sans-serif;
      font-weight: bold;
      color: #444;
      padding: .6em 1.9em .5em .8em;
      line-height:1.3;
    }


    /* Custom arrow sits on top of the select - could be an image, SVG, icon font, etc. or the arrow could just baked into the bg image on the select. Note this si a 2x image so it will look bad in browsers that don't support background-size. In production, you'd handle this resolution switch via media query but this is a demo. */

    .custom-select::after {
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      width: 9px;
      height: 8px;
      top: 50%;
      right: 1em;
      margin-top:-4px;
      background-image: url(http://filamentgroup.com/files/select-arrow.png);
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: 100%;
      z-index: 2;
      /* These hacks make the select behind the arrow clickable in some browsers */
      pointer-events:none;
    }


    /* Hover style */
    .custom-select:hover {
      border:1px solid #888;
    }

    /* Focus style */
    .custom-select select:focus {
      outline:none;
      box-shadow: 0 0 1px 3px rgba(180,222,250, 1);
      background-color:transparent;
      color: #222;
      border:1px solid #aaa;
    }

    /* Set options to normal weight */
    .custom-select option {
      font-weight:normal;
    }






    /* ------------------------------------  */
    /* START OF UGLY BROWSER-SPECIFIC HACKS */
    /* ----------------------------------  */

    /* OPERA - Pre-Blink nix the custom arrow, go with a native select button to keep it simple. Targeted via this hack http://browserhacks.com/#hack-a3f166304aafed524566bc6814e1d5c7 */
    x:-o-prefocus, .custom-select::after {
      display:none;
    }

    /* IE 10/11+ - This hides native dropdown button arrow so it will have the custom appearance, IE 9 and earlier get a native select - targeting media query hack via http://browserhacks.com/#hack-28f493d247a12ab654f6c3637f6978d5 - looking for better ways to achieve this targeting */
    /* The second rule removes the odd blue bg color behind the text in the select button in IE 10/11 and sets the text color to match the focus style's - fix via http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17553300/change-ie-background-color-on-unopened-focused-select-box */
    @media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: active), (-ms-high-contrast: none) {
      .custom-select select::-ms-expand {
        display: none;
      }
      .custom-select select:focus::-ms-value {
        background: transparent;
        color: #222;
      }
    }


    /* FIREFOX won't let us hide the native select arrow, so we have to make it wider than needed and clip it via overflow on the parent container. The percentage width is a fallback since FF 4+ supports calc() so we can just add a fixed amount of extra width to push the native arrow out of view. We're applying this hack across all FF versions because all the previous hacks were too fragile and complex. You might want to consider not using this hack and using the native select arrow in FF. Note this makes the menus wider than the select button because they display at the specified width and aren't clipped. Targeting hack via http://browserhacks.com/#hack-758bff81c5c32351b02e10480b5ed48e */
    /* Show only the native arrow */
    @-moz-document url-prefix() {
      .custom-select {
        overflow: hidden;
      }
      .custom-select select {
        width: 120%;
        width: -moz-calc(100% + 3em);
        width: calc(100% + em);
      }

    }

    /* Firefox focus has odd artifacts around the text, this kills that. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:-moz-focusring */
    .custom-select select:-moz-focusring {
      color: transparent;
      text-shadow: 0 0 0 #000;
    }



    /* ------------------------------------  */
    /*  END OF UGLY BROWSER-SPECIFIC HACKS   */
    /* ------------------------------------  */
```

Reference: http://jsfiddle.net/xvushd7x/

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to make the `select` element in Firefox look like it does in Chrome (as of this writing). This CSS includes the svg to replace the down chevron.

```css
  select {
    width: 100px;
    height: 30px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background-color: white;
    @-moz-document url-prefix() {
      -moz-appearance: none;
      background: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='16' height='16' viewBox='0 0 24 24' fill='none' stroke='%23000' stroke-width='2' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-linejoin='round'%3E%3Cpolyline points='6 9 12 15 18 9'/%3E%3C/svg%3E") no-repeat center right;
    }
  }
```

```html
<select>
<option>The quick</option>
<option>Brown fox</option>
<option>Jumps over</option>
<option>The lazy</option>
<option>Doggo</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Nice minimal solution making use of a media query for Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

To style a select box element in Firefox, you can use CSS to target the specific elements and set custom styling properties. Here is an example of how you can style a select box element for Firefox:

```css
/* Target the select element */ 
select { 
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; color: #333; 
  width: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #fff; 
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none; 
  background-image: url("down-arrow.png");
  background-position: center right;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 10px;
}

/* Target the select arrow button */
select::-moz-focus-inner {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
}

/* Target the dropdown menu */
select option { 
 font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; color: #333; 
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

/* Target the selected option * / 
select option:checked { font-weight: bold; }
```

```html
<select>
<option>One</option>
<option>Two</option>
<option>Three</option>
<option>Four</option>
</select>
```

This CSS code will style the select box element to have a custom font, padding, border, background color, and a custom down arrow icon. It also removes the default styling for the select box and sets custom styles for the dropdown menu options and the selected option. Be sure to update the file path in the background-image property to point to your own down arrow icon image.

You can add this CSS code to your HTML file by using a  tag in the  section of your document, or you can link an external CSS file using a <link> tag.

Note: This code is specifically for Firefox and may not work as intended in other browsers.