# Remove custom Drop Down list selected background color from Internet Explorer 9 & its below version

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net

I have asp.net app in which I have one dropdown.

I want to remove dropdown selected default blue background color. shown in below image 
I have apply all solution of below link none of works. I want to remove blue color when we focus out or select another tag.

[Change IE background color on unopened, focused select box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17553300/change-ie-background-color-on-unopened-focused-select-box)

[image]

I am facing this only in IE9 & its below versions. Not other browser like chrome,firefox,etc even i am not facing this issue in internet explorer 10 & above version

I have try following css

```
dropdownId:focus::-ms-value{
    background-color:white;
    color:#000;
}
```

is any possible way using css if we want to do using **select tag** Id element or using javascript/jquery/CSS.

Comment: Try this: `#dropdownId option:checked {
    background: red;
}`

Comment: Sorry not working pls write specific CSS or Jquery.

Comment: @mplungjan I have tried all solution non of works so I have asked question. You put link of which same like my question but non of solution is works.

Answer (score -1):

You can create a specific style sheet for IE 8 and lower:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie8-and-lower.css" />
<![endif]-->
```