# What is -ms-value

Tags: css, internet-explorer-11

I found a solution for an IE specific issue here and that worked for me:
[Change IE background color on unopened, focused select box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17553300/change-ie-background-color-on-unopened-focused-select-box)

But I just cant find anywhere what does -ms-value mean?

The only thing I can figure out is ms means MicroSoft, so its for IE specific settings but can someone plz share some link or information where we can find more details around this.

**What does -ms-value mean?**

Comment: Did you click on the link "more info here"?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::-ms-value

Comment: ahh!! that link is in some another answer. :-p  thanks !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The :-ms-value CSS pseudo-element is a Microsoft extension that applies rules to the value of a text or password  control or the content of a  control...

Refer to: [-ms-value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::-ms-value) for more information.