# Remove drop-down arrow from <select> element?

Tags: html, css, html-select

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to remove the arrow from a <select> tag in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5912791/how-to-remove-the-arrow-from-a-select-tag-in-firefox)

The arrow only disappears in Chrome. Here is the script that I'm using:

```
<style type="text/css">
select {
    font-family: 'Viga', sans-serif;
    font-size:16px;
    color:#168ACB;
    padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
    margin: 0px 5px 5px 5px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    -moz-border-radius: 8px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 0 #ccc, 0 -1px #eaeaea inset;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 3px 0 #ccc, 0 -1px #eaeaea inset;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 0 #ccc, 0 -1px #eaeaea inset;
    background: #f8f8f8;
    border:none;
    outline:none;
    display: inline-block;
    -webkit-appearance:none;
    -moz-appearance:none;
    appearance:none;
    cursor:pointer;
}
</style>
```

Chrome: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Qv0G.png
Firefox & IE: https://i.stack.imgur.com/w1iut.png

Comment: Tried encapsulating that in a div with overflow hidden? Div will have width < Width of select.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Try seeing this:**

[How to remove the arrow from a select element in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5912791/how-to-remove-the-arrow-from-a-select-tag-in-firefox)

Coincidentally my comment:

> "*Tried encapsulating that in a div with overflow hidden? Div will have width < Width of select.*"

is similar to the highest voted answer.