# How can I remove background of selectbox

Tags: html, css

I have to remove background of selectbox, I have used code like this

```
<select style="background:none;border:none">
<option>A</option>
<option>B</option>
<option>C</option>
<option>D</option>
</select>
```

But In the output arrow appeared.How can I hide that arrow.

Comment: Then how do users know that it is a `dropdown`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove the arrow from a <select> tag in Firefox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5912791/how-to-remove-the-arrow-from-a-select-tag-in-firefox)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `-webkit-appearance:none`

```
<select style="background:none;border:none; -webkit-appearance:none">
```

or add div around and give max width.

```
<div style="width:80px; overflow:hidden">
<select style="background:none;border:none; width:97px">
<option>A</option>
<option>B</option>
<option>C</option>
<option>D</option>
</select>
</div>
```

**[Updated DEMO](http://tinkerbin.com/eUpP5caB)**

Comment: @Sowmya Why would you use `inline` styles?

Comment: It is not working properly,I did only for sample that's why I used in line styles

Comment: @freebird that is only for sample. I hope he knows to add it to style sheet when developing

Comment: @SowmyaShivaram Ya that is true but some might just use them as stated in answer.

Comment: @freebird sry I dnt wanna argue unnecessarily

Comment: @freebird: Most likely because the OP used inline styles. Pushing the styles into a stylesheet and getting them to add a class/ID could confuse him/her. While I understand inline styles aren't exactly best practice, standards aren't really covered by the scope of his question.

Comment: Ya I always used stylesheet while working,  Here if I increase width from 13px to 80px it is not working properly.

Comment: your outer div width should be 20-25px lesser than the select tag width so that the overflow width of the select will be hidden by the outer div.

Comment: we should not use inline styling that will increase are markup of the page so always try to make the code simple neat & clean with minimum markup for styling you have style-sheet file you can do over-there whatever you wants to do

Comment: @Sowmya I got my requirement from your suggestion.(Thank You)

Answer (score 0):

Make select width more than 100% and apply overflow:hidden

```
select {
    overflow:hidden;
    width: 120%;
}
```

See this link and the 2nd answer seems more what you are after!

[How to remove the arrow from a select element in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5912791/how-to-remove-the-arrow-from-a-select-tag-in-firefox)

Comment: I need with 80px width.then what?

Comment: See the 2nd answer in the link :) It will do that

Comment: http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/ Chosen is a JavaScript plugin that makes long, unwieldy select boxes much more user-friendly. It is currently available in both jQuery and Prototype flavors.