# Remove the button inside the dropdownlist

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to hide or remove the arrow button inside a dropdownlist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, at least in webkit: http://jsfiddle.net/zzTjy/1/.

**HTML**

```
<select>
    <option>123</option>
</select>
```

**CSS**

```
SELECT { -webkit-appearance: none; }
```

It's worth noting that Mozilla supports `-moz-appearance`, but it doesn't hide the arrow in the dropdown list. This has been an open issue for quite some time.

Mozilla also states:

> Do not use this property on Web sites: not only is it non-standard,
>   but its behavior change from one browser to another.

This may be a bit draconian, but you certainly shouldn't use `appearance` to change the expected behavior of the element.

**Further Reading**

- [More Examples](http://37signals.com/svn/posts/2609-customizing-web-forms-with-css3-and-webkit)
- [Bug to Implement in Mozilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=649849)
- [How to remove the arrow from a select element in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5912791/how-to-remove-the-arrow-from-a-select-tag-in-firefox)

Comment: That's why I said, "in webkit". Webkit is the engine which powers Chrome and Safari, not IE. It's a non-standard approach; the only alternative is to use a custom dropdown list which is not a `select`.