# HTML simulate select on textfield

Tags: html, select, input

I have a textfield

```
 <input type="text"...
```

It shall display items from 1 to 31. If I click in the textfield it should open the values (1 - 31) like in a select field. However I don't want to directly use

```
 <select
```

because I don't like the "down arrow".

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You can [hide the down-arrow in Internet Explorer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15933790/54680). As a general rule, it's best to use the native elements rather than creating similar functionality all your own. You may inadvertently affect accessibility.

Comment: Take a look at this [Custom Drop-down list styling](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/10/04/custom-drop-down-list-styling/)

Comment: does it work with every browser?

Comment: Probably not in older versions of IE.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `multiple` attribute on the `<select>` tag:

```
<select multiple>
    <option value="1">First</option>
    <option value="etc">Others</option>
</select>
```

That will look like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/RSBtJ/1/).

Comment: It should really be a textfield. Only when clicking on the field, the list should show