# CSS hide input checkbox in Internet Explorer

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8

I have the following html input:

```
<label class="selectit">
     <input value="women_shoulder_bags" type="checkbox" id="in-women-15797">Shoulder Bags
</label>
```

I also have the following CSS:

```
.selectit input {
     -webkit-appearance: none;
     -moz-appearance: none;
     -o-appearance: none;
}
```

This works in Safari, Chrome and all others. But in Internet Explorer 8, the checkboxes still show up. My question is, how do I use CSS to hide the input checkboxes in Internet Explorer 8?

Thanks

Comment: `display: none` seems to work fine.. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KJ2cC/).

Comment: The thing is, I use jquery to change the input's background a checked sign when clicked. So if I set it to display none, then the background also gets displayed none when clicked

Comment: `opacity:0` / `visibility:hidden`?

Comment: @Paulie_D Tried `visibility: hidden`, it hides the checkbox but like I said above, it also hides the background checkmark I'm using instead of the default checkbox. So I need a way to hide the default checkbox but still display my own custom checkmark background

Answer (score 4):

To achieve that for ie10+ you can use `::-ms-check` with `display:none`
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh771816(v=vs.85).aspx

```
input::-ms-check{
    display:none
}
```

UPDATE: for ie8, ie9

you can use the same technique in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/23777214/2253257

```
    input::-ms-check {
        /* IE 8 */
        -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
        /* IE 5-7 */
        filter: alpha(opacity=0);
        /* Good browsers :) */
        opacity:0;
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just hide it in every browser? Or is there a reason it should show in Opera?
You could try:

```
.selectit input {
     display: none;
}
```

Comment: The thing is, I use jquery to change the input's background a checked sign when clicked. So if I set it to display none, then the background also gets displayed none when clicked

Comment: Alternatively I can change the background-color of the input checkbox if that is a possibility, do you know how do I do that?

Comment: If you use display:none you aren't able to tab onto the field and it would probably 'confuse' some screen readers

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
.selectit input {
    width: 0px;   /* or right: 100%; */
    position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: margin-left: -20px can't work for me because doing that also hides the checkmark background image which is in the same position as the checkboxes. I haven't tried width: 0px in IE but in Chrome I still see the default checkboxes, just a bit smaller

Comment: In Chrome don't you see the checkbox? It's partially obstructed by the text

Comment: @user2028856 you are posting my old fiddle always.. please update the fiddle. (_check for "update" button in that fiddle and then share the link_)

Comment: @user2028856 looks good to me..? the checkbox is not visible. this is what you want right? please explain clearly and also share a screenshot if possible.

Comment: I totally don't get this. I'm using Chrome on OS X Maverick. http://snag.gy/yFREa.jpg

Comment: @user2028856 hmm seems buggy.. try this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KJ2cC/4/). also you can make it better by giving `right` property more than `100%` with parent container set to `overflow: hidden`.

Comment: This is what I see http://snag.gy/WXzp4.jpg  Are you able to send me a screenshot of what you see?

Comment: Try giving `right: 200%` or `visibility: hidden` (_this should work_). here I can see good check this [screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/zW9vAH2.png).

Comment: I guess my issue can't be resolve so easily. I do manage to get the default checkbox to become hidden but then the background custom checkmark doesn't get displayed anymore

Comment: @user2028856 I can't understand what you mean by background custom checkmark.. can you please make a small fiddle of that?