# Clearing the background of a <select> element's pulldown button with CSS

Tags: html, css, customization, mozilla, html-select

So I have a `<select>` element that I need to customize. Essentially I just want it to look like text, but when the user clicks on it, the pulldown choices appear. It would be preferred to show the little arrows indicating the multiple choices, but I could add that as an image myself.

However, here is the issue.

Via CSS, I customize this element using:

```
#FromPopup {
            background: none; <--
            border: none;  <-----
            margin-left: 8px;
            position: relative;
            cursor: pointer;
            height: 5px;
            margin-top: -10px;
}
```

I have little arrows showing the two essential rules.

This clears the background and removes the border and actually almost works, however the little arrow pulldown button is still shown, and looks like Win Classic.

[image: Not cool]

Is it possible to hide the background and border of the pulldown button?

I only care for working with Mozilla platforms here. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally you could use [`-moz-appearance:none`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/-moz-appearance) but there is a bug with the arrow of the `select` elements..

Read this bug report : https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=649849

---

Maybe a trick like wrapping an element around your `select` and then using `:after` to put an element on top of it..

```
<div class="select-container">
    <select>
        <option>This is some option</option>
        <option>This is some option</option>
        <option>This is some option</option>
        <option>This is some option</option>
        <option>This is some option</option>
        <option>This is some option</option>
    </select>
</div>

.select-container {
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative
}
.select-container:after {
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    top:0;
    width:17px;
    height:100%;
    z-index:10;
    background-color:white;
}
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/K8MJB/1/

Comment: Cool thanks. I prefer this solution. I was wwondering if something like this was possible.

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen:

[How to remove the arrow from a select element in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5912791/how-to-remove-the-arrow-from-a-select-tag-in-firefox)

It looks like you're limited with your possibilities but there are a few ideas and solutions there.  One could be just to to eliminate the arrow with something like this:

```
select {
   overflow:hidden;
   width: 120%;
}
```

Then you're free to add your own.

Comment: I guess is the approach I will take. Thanks.