# options for search TextField in navbar

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-select

Is it possible that the user could select from the utility dropdown (see picture below) a search option which will effect the search text field?

[image]

Or is it possible merge the dropdown and search text field together?

Comment: perhaps bootstrap typeahead is what you're looking for? https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you will be able to do this leveraging [input-groups](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups). But the docs also mention:

> Avoid using  elements here as they cannot be fully styled in
>   WebKit browsers.

HTML to integrate a `<select>` in the navbar:

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-left select-search" role="search">
<div class="input-group">
<span class="input-group-addon">        
<select class="form-control">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
  <option>5</option>
</select>
</span>
<input type="text" class="form-control">
</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Then apply the following CSS:

```
    .select-search .input-group-addon {
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    }
    .select-search .input-group .input-group-addon > select.form-control {
    border-top-left-radius: 4px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 4px; 
    }
```

Demo: http://www.bootply.com/8zPGZ9ySOl

I found this works well in chrome, but in firefox the select arrow got some button like styling:

[image]

I'm not sure how to fix the style of the select arrow here. Style the select with `-moz-appearance:none` or `-moz-appearance:menulist` won't help. Possible related to: [Clearing the background of a <select> element's pulldown button with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16254777/clearing-the-background-of-a-select-elements-pulldown-button-with-css)