# Custom select not cross-browser appropriate

Tags: html, css

So I wanted a custom select box and I did the following :

html :

```
<div class="select">
   <select name="Step_01_Roof_Width" onChange="GetWidth();" class="Step_01_SelectBox" id="Step_01_Select_Width">
</div>
```

css :

```
 .select select
{
    width:              300px;
    background:         transparent;
    padding:            5px;
    font-size:          10px;
    line-height:        1;
    border:             0;
    border-radius:      0;
    height:             19px;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}

.select
{
    width:              270px;
    height:             19px;
    border-radius:      15px;
    border:             black solid 1px;
    background:         url(/wp-content/themes/blackbird/phpwizard/HTML5Application/public_html/images/Step_01/selectarrow.png) no-repeat right white ;
}
```

However, this only works for chrome and safari as far as I know, firefox and IE give some problems with this. You can view it here : http://www.solar-discounter.nl/uw-pv-systeem/ If anyone has any idea on how to achieve the chrome and safari example on firefox and IE, that would be such a big help to me!
Thanks for reading.

Comment: You should put quotes in your url(''). The link you provided is not working

Comment: @Bikiew — Quotes inside `url()` are optional.

Comment: Yeah, It was my fault I posted a wrong url :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for : [How to remove the arrow from a select element in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5912791/how-to-remove-the-arrow-from-a-)

Add `opacity:0;` to `.select select` and a div with position absolute before your select.
You can then update the div text with javascript/jquery.

Comment: Thanks, your answer in combination with the other question you've posted helped me alot!