# How to remove the default arrow icon from a dropdown list (select element)?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, html-select

I want to remove the dropdown arrow from a HTML `<select>` element. For example:

```
<select style="width:30px;-webkit-appearance: none;">
    <option>2000</option>
    <option>2001</option>
    <option>2002</option>
    ...
</select>
```

How to do it in Opera, Firefox and Internet Explorer?

[image]

Comment: Some answers/hacks for hiding it in Firefox - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5912791/how-to-remove-the-arrow-from-a-select-tag-in-firefox

Comment: [**appearance**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-moz-appearance)
`#slectType { -webkit-appearance: none; appearance: none /*menulist*/ `[**!important**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)`; max-width: 300px; line-height: 0px;} 
input[type='text'], select {max-height: 30px;max-width: 300px; text-align-last: center; /*text-indent: 5px;*/}
button:hover {color: #FFF;background-color: #566977;box-shadow:none;border-color: #759AB5;}
#errorMSG{z-index: 2147483647;}`
Browses[ CH:-webkit, FF:-moz, IE:-ms, Oprea:-o];

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove Select arrow on IE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20163079/remove-select-arrow-on-ie)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML hide Select drop down arrow with css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27435192/html-hide-select-drop-down-arrow-with-css)

Comment: For those who use Tailwind, add this class: `appearance-none`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you use [**TailwindCSS**](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/appearance)
You may take advantage of the `appearance-none` class.

```html
<select class="appearance-none">
  <option>Yes</option>
  <option>No</option>
  <option>Maybe</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Anyone know how to get this to work for selects using the "multiple" attribute?

Answer (score 424):

There's no need for hacks or overflow. There's a pseudo-element for the dropdown arrow on IE:

```
select::-ms-expand {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: because the question was how to remove the dropdown arrow in IE. IE9 doesn't have this functionality, but this works in IE10. so unless you're using windows XP, you should be using IE10 anyway. IE11 is almost out. other option is an ugly CSS hack to hide the actual dropdown button and make your own.

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19224129/2009533) here's the ugly hack to hide the overflow

Comment: Works in IE11. Gracias!

Comment: This did not work in Firefox. Use Varun Rathore's solution below for Firefox.

Comment: this is for IE only. of course it won't work in Firefox.

Comment: great, exactly what I was looking for. I had custom arrow image added and hide the default, which was working for other browsers but Edge was showing 2. Now its fixed.

Comment: Not quite sure why this has green tick. It doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 391):

The previously mentioned solutions work well with chrome but not on Firefox.

I found a [Solution](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=649849#c84) that works well both in Chrome and Firefox(not on IE). Add the following attributes to the CSS for your SELECTelement and adjust the margin-top to suit your needs.

```css
select {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  text-indent: 1px;
  text-overflow: '';
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option>one</option>
  <option>two</option>
  <option>three</option>

</select>
```

Comment: This trick stopped working on Firefox as of version 31 (in Nightly build as of May 2014). Let's see what can be done in the meanwhile. This gist I wrote has the full lowdown: https://gist.github.com/joaocunha/6273016/

Comment: Joäo Cunha's method checked and used succesfully. When you check it out, don't forget to open the link in firefox!

Comment: It worked for me. I wanted to use it for wkhtmltopdf to generate pdf from html. Thanks

Comment: text-indent only affects the active option, whereas padding-left affects both the selected option and the options in the drop-down, which looks cleaner IMO. I don't see the need for the text-overflow, if you simply want to remove the arrow.

Answer (score 251):

**Simple way to remove drop down arrow from select**

```css
select {
  /* for Firefox */
  -moz-appearance: none;
  /* for Chrome */
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

/* For IE10 */
select::-ms-expand {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option>2000</option>
  <option>2001</option>
  <option>2002</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I just used `appearance: none` for Chrome and Firefox Quantum (v59 and up). I.e. **no need [vendor prefixes** anymore](https://caniuse.com/#search=appearance).

Comment: @CPHPython Most browsers as of this comment still have a "partial support with prefix" tag on them...

Comment: @CPHPython you need to have [Autoprefixer](https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer) installed on your project for the unprefixed `appearance: none` to work. Most browsers still need the prefixes.

Comment: @DanielTonon oh, perhaps I was using some postcss package like that. I do not remember exactly, but I think I checked the browser's inspector before commenting.

Comment: This hsould be the accepted answer, as it actually answers the question :-)

Answer (score 71):

Try this :

```
select {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    padding: 2px 30px 2px 2px;
    border: none;
}
```

JS Bin : http://jsbin.com/aniyu4/2/edit

If you use Internet Explorer :

```
select {
    overflow:hidden;
    width: 120%;
}
```

Or you can use Choosen : http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/

Comment: Did you test [your JSBin](http://jsbin.com/aniyu4/2/edit) in IE and firefox? I still see the built in dropdown arrow in both.

Comment: Check with Choosen, I think it's the best choice.

Comment: "If you use Internet Explorer"? You need to consider the large % of the population who DO use IE and cater for them regardless

Comment: Our sites user stats are as follows: 5.21% IE or 2.37% Edge

Comment: "If you use IE" would be correct, it'd be better suited to say "If you need to support IE" but in this day and age, your technology should be properly targeted towards your audience, if you're running a web developer targeted website then I doubt you'll be needing to support ANY versions of IE.

Answer (score 17):

Try This:

HTML:

```
<div class="customselect">
    <select>
    <option>2000</option>
    <option>2001</option>
    <option>2002</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.customselect {
    width: 70px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.customselect select {
   width: 100px;
   -moz-appearance: none;
   -webkit-appearance: none;
   appearance: none;
}
```

Answer (score 15):

Try this it works for me,

```html
<style>
    select{
        border: 0 !important;  /*Removes border*/
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        -moz-appearance: none;
        appearance: none;
        text-overflow:'';
        text-indent: 0.01px; /* Removes default arrow from firefox*/
        text-overflow: "";  /*Removes default arrow from firefox*/
    }
    select::-ms-expand {
        display: none;
    }
    .select-wrapper
    {
        padding-left:0px;
        overflow:hidden;
    }
</style>
    
<div class="select-wrapper">
     <select> ... </select>
</div>
```

You can not hide but using overflow hidden you can actually make it disappear.

Answer (score 14):

In my case (on latest Mozilla version 94.0.2),

```css
select {
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
}
```

doesnt work but after checking the css I found the solution :

- Arrow is contain in `background-image` so I solved it by just adding `background-image: none;`

I recommend use all rules

```css
select {
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  background-image: none;
}
```

Comment: This is the solution - works if a select has the "multiple" attribute applied too.

Answer (score 7):

Just wanted to complete the thread. 
To be very clear this does not works in IE9, however we can do it by little css trick.

```
<div class="customselect">
    <select>
    <option>2000</option>
    <option>2001</option>
    <option>2002</option>
    </select>
</div>

.customselect {
    width: 80px;
    overflow: hidden;
   border:1px solid;
}

.customselect select {
   width: 100px;
   border:none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
   -webkit-appearance: none;
   appearance: none;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

As I answered in [Remove Select arrow on IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20163079/remove-select-arrow-on-ie/43258801#43258801)

In case you want to use the class and pseudo-class:

`.simple-control` is your css class

`:disabled` is pseudo class

```
select.simple-control:disabled{
         /*For FireFox*/
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        /*For Chrome*/
        -moz-appearance: none;
}

/*For IE10+*/
select:disabled.simple-control::-ms-expand {
        display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
select{
padding: 11px 50px 11px 10px;
background: rgba(255,255,255,1);
border-radius: 7px;
-webkit-border-radius: 7px;
-moz-border-radius: 7px;
border: 0;
-webkit-appearance: none;
-moz-appearance: none;
appearance: none;
color: #8ba2d4;
```

}

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do this with a fully functional cross browser support.

Try taking a div of 50 pixels suppose and float a desired drop-down icon of your choice at the right of this

Now within that div, add the select tag with a width of 55 pixels maybe (something more than the container's width)

I think you'll get what you want.

In case you do not want any drop icon at the right, just do all the steps except for floating the image at the right. Set outline:0 on focus for the select tag. that's it

Comment: I cannot get no help from these hints. Can anybody give adequate code here? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

there's a library called DropKick.js that replaces the normal select dropdowns with HTML/CSS so you can fully style and control them with javascript. http://dropkickjs.com/

Answer (score 2):

Works for all browsers and all versions:

**JS**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {    
    var widthOfSelect = $("#first").width();
    widthOfSelect = widthOfSelect - 13;
    //alert(widthOfSelect);
    jQuery('#first').wrap("<div id='sss' style='width: "+widthOfSelect+"px; overflow: hidden; border-right: #000 1px solid;' width=20></div>");
});
```

**HTML**

```
<select class="first" id="first">
  <option>option1</option>
  <option>option2</option>
  <option>option3</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

one simple and easy way to hide the caret icon on select html tag is to add the background-image to it in css with value as none along with appearance none;

```css
select.without-icon {appearance:none;background-image:url('');}
```

```html
<label>with Icon</label>
<select class="with-icon">
<option value="select" selected>Select</option>
<option value="Html Css">HTML CSS </option>
<option value="web development">Web Development</option>
<option value="Front End">Front End</option>
<option value="Programming">Programming</option>
</select>

<label>Without Icon</label>
<select class="without-icon">
<option value="select" selected>Select</option>
<option value="Html Css">HTML CSS </option>
<option value="web development">Web Development</option>
<option value="Front End">Front End</option>
<option value="Programming">Programming</option>
</select>
```

, just like this:

```
background-image:url('');
```

Answer (score 0):

It works for me:

```
.dropdown-toggle::after {
    content: none;
}
```