# Remove Select arrow on IE

Tags: html, css, html-select

I have select element, i want to remove the arrow, then i can add other icon..
i can do that for Firefox Safari and Chrome,
but this didn't work on **IE9**.

```
.styled-select select 
{
    border: 0 !important;  /*Removes border*/
    -webkit-appearance: none;  /*Removes default chrome and safari style*/
    -moz-appearance: none;  /*Removes default style Firefox*/
    background: url('select_icon.png')  no-repeat;
     background-position: 179px 7px;
     text-indent: 0.01px;
     text-overflow: "";
     color: #FCAF17;
     width:200px;
 }
```

SEE [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kBWYd/) on **IE9**.
all what i need is remove the arrow in ie9
Please JSFIDDLE answer.

Comment: It may not be possible at all. Browsers (especially IE) have been traditionally reluctant to offer extended styling options of their widgets.

Comment: You can't do this with just CSS, but I believe there are JS libraries for styling forms that can do this. Google should know.

Comment: @Alberto this question has been answer before 2 years :) if you think you have answer you can insert it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select removing dropdown arrow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16603979/select-removing-dropdown-arrow)

Answer (score 329, accepted):

In IE9, it is possible with [purely a hack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19408178/1671639) as advised by @Spudley.  Since you've customized height and width of the div and select, you need to change `div:before` css to match yours.

In case if it is IE10 then using below css3 it is possible

```css
select::-ms-expand {
    display: none;
}
```

However if you're interested in jQuery plugin, try **`Chosen.js`** or you can create your own in js.

Comment: @Moath Howari I have modified you fiddle, check this in IE9 http://jsfiddle.net/kBWYd/6/

Comment: @PraveenJeganathan Selectbox have one bug as well. As we click on just  right corner of the dropdown it is not working. Can we do something for this ?

Comment: @Praveen thing is, then the right side is not clickable.

Comment: @ManjitSingh & Tom Roggero - This is pretty hacky but if you need that space clickable you can replace `display: none;` with `opacity: .01`. It'll be almost impossible to see it but it will still be clickable.

Comment: Any way to make it appears when mouse hover ?  I tried :

select::-ms-expand:hover

But no luck

Comment: @MarcRoussel based on this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SRGLu/1443/) this can be written like `select:hover::-ms-expand` hover state for pseudo element is as mentioned `selector:state::pseudo`.  I couldn't test with IE yet worth a try :)

Comment: @Praveen I tried and it's not working.  I mean the select:hover::-ms-expand

Comment: any ie11 only hack?

Answer (score 6):

I would suggest mine solution that you can find  [in this GitHub repo](https://github.com/Ferie/Cross-browser_Custom_HTML_Select_Tag_Arrow).
**This works also for IE8 and IE9** with a custom arrow that comes from an icon font.

[Examples of Custom Cross Browser Drop-down](http://riccardoandreatta.com/web-app/HTML_Select_tag_custom_arrow/HTML_Select_tag_custom_arrow_-_Example.html) in action: check them with all your browsers to see the cross-browser feature.

Anyway, let's start with the modern browsers and then we will see the solution for the older ones.

#### Drop-down Arrow for Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Internet Explorer 10+

For these browser, it is easy to *set the same background image for the drop-down* in order to have the same arrow.

To do so, you have to reset the browser's default style for the `select` tag and set new background rules (like suggested before).

```
select {
    /* you should keep these firsts rules in place to maintain cross-browser behaviour */
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    -o-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    background-image: url('<custom_arrow_image_url_here>');
    background-position: 98% center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    outline: none;
    ...
}
```

The `appearance` rules are set to none to reset browsers default ones, if you want to have the same aspect for each arrow, you should keep them in place.

The `background` rules in the examples are set with SVG inline images that represent different arrows. They are positioned 98% from left to keep some margin to the right border (you can easily modify the position as you wish).

In order to maintain the correct cross-browser behavior, the only other rule that have to be left in place is the `outline`. This rule resets the default border that appears (in some browsers) when the element is clicked. All the others rules can be easily modified if needed.

#### Drop-down Arrow for Internet Explorer 8 (IE8) and Internet Explorer 9 (IE9) using Icon Font

This is the harder part... Or maybe not.

There is no standard rule to hide the default arrows for these browsers (like the `select::-ms-expand` for IE10+). The solution is to **hide the part of the *drop-down* that contains the default arrow** and insert an arrow icon font (or a SVG, if you prefer) similar to the SVG that is used in the other browsers (see the `select` CSS rule for more details about the inline SVG used).

The very first step is to set a class that can recognize the browser: this is the reason why I have used the conditional IE IFs at the beginning of the code. These IFs are used to attach specific classes to the `html` tag to recognize the older IE browser.

After that, every `select` in the HTML have to be wrapped by a `div` (or whatever tag that can wraps an element). At this wrapper just add the class that contains the icon font.

```
<div class="selectTagWrapper prefix-icon-arrow-down-fill">
    ...
</div>
```

In easy words, this wrapper is used to simulate the `select` tag.

To act like a drop-down, the wrapper must have a border, because we hide the one that comes from the `select`.

Notice that we cannot use the `select` border because we have to hide the default arrow lengthening it 25% more than the wrapper. Consequently its right border should not be visible because we hide this 25% more by the `overflow: hidden` rule applied to the `select` itself.

The custom arrow icon-font is placed in the pseudo class `:before` where the rule `content` contains the reference for the arrow (in this case it is a right parenthesis).

We also place this arrow in an absolute position to center it as much as possible (if you use different icon fonts, remember to adjust them opportunely by changing top and left values and the font size).

```
.ie8 .prefix-icon-arrow-down-fill:before,
.ie9 .prefix-icon-arrow-down-fill:before {
    content: ")";
    position: absolute;
    top: 43%;
    left: 93%;
    font-size: 6px;
    ...
}
```

You can easily create and substitute the background arrow or the icon font arrow, with every one that you want simply changing it in the `background-image` rule or making a new icon font file by yourself.

Answer (score 5):

In case you want to use the class and pseudo-class:

`.simple-control` is your css class

`:disabled` is pseudo class

```css
select.simple-control:disabled {
  /*For FireFox*/
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  /*For Chrome*/
  -moz-appearance: none;
}
    
/*For IE10+*/
select:disabled.simple-control::-ms-expand {
  display: none;
}
```