# How to remove default arrow form <select> in Firefox (Firefox version 30) and IE

Tags: html, css, firefox, select, cross-browser

Is there a way to hide the arrow of a  element in Firefox and IE, I know this question is already asked here and answered but doesn't work on FF30 anymore.

Here's an example of what I'm doing:

```css
select {
  border: 0 !important;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  background: url(../images/select-arrow.png) no-repeat 95% 50% #ffffff;
  background-size: 12%;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #b4b4b4;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-indent: 0.01px;
  text-overflow: "";
}
```

```html
<select class="col-xm-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8 pull-right">
  <option selected="selected" icon="">Sort Topics</i>
  </option>

  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
</select>
```

I just want to remove the default arrow icon in firefox & IE.he -moz-appearance: none doesn't get rid of the dropdown icon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```
select::-ms-expand {
   display: none;
}
```

for hiding dropdown arrow in IE and for more [info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20163079/remove-select-arrow-on-ie).

and for firefox us can use this:

```
-webkit-appearance: none;
-moz-appearance: none;
 appearance: none;
```

see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9vmrqw6y/3/): 
see this [link](http://seriousaboutseo.com/hiding-select-arrow-firefox-30) and [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23920990/firefox-30-is-not-hiding-select-box-arrows-anymore)

let me know if you still have issues with arrow

thanks

Comment: select::-ms-expand {
   display: none;
}   it's works on IE :)

Comment: -webkit-appearance: none;
-moz-appearance: none;
 appearance: none;

Already used but doesn't get rid of dropdown icon on firefox

Comment: check my link you will surely get some info

Answer (score 0):

I updated my moz version now I am using version 37.0.2
firefox solved this bug on newer version