# How to change `select` element for IE?

Tags: css

I saw [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27641804/287316) to render an arrow on `select` element:

```
select {
    width: 268px;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 1;
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 5px;
    height: 34px;
    background: url(http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/cc_mono_icon_set/blacks/16x16/br_down.png) no-repeat right #ddd;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    background-position-x: 244px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qhCsJ/4120/

It works great for Chrome.

For Firefox the `-moz-appearance: none;` will do the trick.

But for IE I have no idea.

Answer (score 0):

Add this (IE 10 + I guess):

```
select::-ms-expand {
    display: none;
}
```

credits here: [Remove Select arrow on IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20163079/remove-select-arrow-on-ie)

For IE9, wrap your select with a `div` and use something like this (a image that will be over the original one):

```
select {
    width: 268px;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 1;
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 5px;
    height: 34px;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    background-position-x: 244px;
}

select::-ms-expand {
    display: none;
}

div {
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
    border:solid black 1px;
    z-index:0
}
div select {
    z-index:1;
}

div:before {
    background: url(http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/cc_mono_icon_set/blacks/16x16/br_up.png) no-repeat right #ddd;
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    content:'';
    right:6px;
    top:5px;
    height:1em;
    width:1em;
    margin:2px;
    z-index:5;
}
```

IE 8 or before you can't.