# Style a select on Microsoft Internet Explorer

Tags: css, internet-explorer, select, internet-explorer-11

I'm fixing all style bugs in IE11 on a website and I'm trying to figure how to fix the awful select of this browser - aside: why not adequate the architecture to all other browsers? This thing drives me crazy. How can I remove that terrible arrow on the right?

[Select in Microsoft IE11 show a box with arrow on the right. How to style it?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FAhNr.png)

Comment: Just thank God on your knees you were not developing during the times of IE5/5.5/6/7/8

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20163079/remove-select-arrow-on-ie