# Custom SELECT drop down icon not display in IE

Tags: html, css

I am using the custom drop down arrow for SELECT tag it is working fine in other browser but not supporting in IE.
Here is the code

**HTML**

```
<select class="form-control" id="questionType">
  <option>Select</option>
  <option>General Question</option>
  <option>Technical Question</option>
</select>
```

**CSS**

```
select::-ms-expand {
    display: none;
}
select.form-control {
  background: #f0f0f0 url('https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ionicons/512/icon-arrow-down-b-128.png') no-repeat right center;
  background-size: 16px;
  -moz-appearance:none; /* Firefox */
  -webkit-appearance:none; /* Safari and Chrome */
  appearance:none;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/alpeshlahad/tdm83qnc/2/)**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove Select arrow on IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20163079/remove-select-arrow-on-ie)

Comment: select element is not working on IE