# Bootstrap Dropdown doesn't style correctly in Internet Explorer

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using twitter bootstrap classes in my angular project. For a dropdown menu the styles work fine in Chrome but when I load it into IE 11, it does not style properly. In particular the dropdown arrow button.

Has anyone else had this issue with IE? How would I resolve this? Please see a comparison photo below of my issue.

[image]

My html section below as well, any comments welcome thanks in advance!

```
 <select class=" btn btn-default"  ng-options="obj for obj in data.finding"
                      ng-model="gapSection.finding"  >
                      <option value="">Please select</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I confirm that this is the case when using Bootstrap 3.3.2.

Answer (score 3):

I just solved for IE using :

```
select::-ms-expand {
    border:none;
    background:#fff;
}
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25923916/769678)

Answer (score 2):

Add this on your css file

```
select::-ms-expand {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: You may want to explain what your code does / why you think it will resolve the problem (maybe link to some sources?).

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use bootstrap class `form-control` on HTML tag `select` for it to render correctly:

```
<select class="form-control">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap 3 drops support for Internet Explorer 7, but you can add it back by simply adding conditional CSS called bootstrap-ie7.css.

**here is the download link::** https://github.com/coliff/bootstrap-ie7

Comment: The author is talking about IE11 though.