# how to change the triangle icon in drop down list to a customized icon in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I am trying to create a few drop down lists,but I need to have a customized icon ,not the vintage black triangle .I tried a few tricks from net ,but does not serve my propose.

I believe it is  possible using JavaScript or j query, but I have no idea.
How to do that ??

Comment: show some of your efforts which you alredy tried

Comment: they are all using css tricks like setting the background with a complete pic ,which is pathetic in IE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do by this way,

#### Check this <kbd>[**demo jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/umarkashmiri/etFuL/1/)</kbd>

#### CSS

```
select {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    text-indent: 1px;
    text-overflow: '';
    background: url("YOUR IMAGE") no-repeat right center;
}

select::-ms-expand {
    display: none;
}
```

#### HTML

```
<div class="dropdown">
     <p>Show: </p>

     <select>
          <option> Balloon</option>
          <option> Mango</option>
          <option> Banana</option>
     </select>
</div>
```

Comment: will it work in IE and firefox ,just asking I have one similar which dint worked properly

Comment: -webkit- will make it work in safari and chrome, -moz- will make it work in firefox, appearance is just for future browsers to render it without prefixes, as I've declared ::-ms-expand, it will work on IE 8+, if you want to work it on before versions, change :: to :

Comment: I will accept this as answer am using IE 10 ,the thing is like when am viewing it in chrome and firefox ,its ok ,but in IE ,I can  not see the image ,the values take over the full space,how to remove that

Comment: That's weired. Please note that IE9 less won't work with this trick as there was no real CSS method to do so. But surely, you can "hack" to remove dropdown from IE9 lesser browsers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19407332/how-to-hide-drop-down-arrow-in-ie9

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. I have made a sample for you on [Fiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/umarkashmiri/etFuL/)

```
<div class="dropdown">
      <p>Show: </p>
        <select>
         <option> Balloon</option>
         <option> Mango</option>
         <option> Banana</option>
       </select>
</div> 


.dropdown p {
    display: inline-block;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.dropdown select {

      border: 0 !important; 
      -webkit-appearance: none;
      -moz-appearance: none; 
      background: url('https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSePVWt6a83sB0JECOwilcf11eZsK_ciMNH-eUSpNpXJCKWLav7') no-repeat right; 
      background-position: 82px 7px;  
      width: 100px; 
      text-indent: 0.01px; 
      text-overflow: "";  
      color: #1455a2;
}
```

Hope this will help

Comment: thanks i checked the fiddle ,but i need a customized image at the end ,this fiddle does not have that

Comment: Hey you have to set the image position only. Look now i have updated
http://jsfiddle.net/umarkashmiri/etFuL/1/

Comment: I had not appropriate image... but when you set your own just set its background-postion property

Comment: i have marked another answer ,which was also helpful,but that answer came earlier than also ,but never less than a heartfelt thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have already accepted another answer ,according to the question the answer was almost to the point.However I dint used the answer,The disadvantages are like u need to have the proper image(Which I dint had) to put(I needed a diamond shape and with in that another triangle screen short attached ) and again it was not working in IE.So ,what exactly I did is ,I  draw the whole thing (the diamond and white triangle inside it) in canvas and positioned it perfectly and with `pointer-events:none;`the canvas was allowed to pass the clicks to the actual drop down list.

This is the screen short of what exactly needed

[image]