# How to delete default dropdown arrow in Internet Explorer 8 IE8?

Tags: css, select, drop-down-menu

This css code doesn't work.

```
select::-ms-expand {
    display: none;
}
```

Code of my dropdown:

```
select::-ms-expand {
    display: none;
}

select {
    width: 100px;
    height: 30px;
    -webkit-appearance: none; /* gets rid of default appearance in Webkit browsers*/
    -moz-appearance: none; /* Get rid of default appearance for older Firefox browsers */
    -ms-appearance: none; /* get rid of default appearance for IE8, 9 and 10*/
    appearance: none;
    background-color: none;
    border: none;
    border-top-right-radius: 0px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:0px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius:0px;
    -moz-border-bottom-right-radius:0px;
    background-image: url('../img/arrow_question.png');
    background-position: center;
    background-size: 30%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

[image]

I've been looking for a long time and can't find a solution.

Comment: please provide the working code as well

Comment: this will help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19407332/how-to-hide-drop-down-arrow-in-ie9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This helped:

```
div {
    width: 80px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
select {
    width: 100px;
    border: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `appearance: none;` to achieve what you are looking for.

**For instance,**

```
select{
    appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    background: url("yourBackroundImagePath.extension") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;

}
select::-ms-expand{
    display: none;
}
```

Hope this helps.