# Dropdown style not rendering properly in ff and IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, firefox

I am trying to customize the dropdown with these style.The style rendering properly in Chrome but in IE anf FF default stle is overriding the css.

here is the Css style for dropdown

http://jsfiddle.net/eVLY9/

```
<select class="ddText dropdown-select" id="opt" style="width: 90px;">
```

Comment: `<select>` elements are not reliably `style`-able. You may replace it with a `<ul>` or (ew...) a jQuery plugin, but in general you should not use [non-native UI](http://blog.codinghorror.com/non-native-ui-sucks/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As saikiran.vsk suggested in FF the you can use

```
select {
    -moz-appearance: none;
    text-indent: 0.01px;
    text-overflow: "";
}
```

and in IE this will work , but IE 9+

```
select::-ms-expand{ display:none; }
```

you can add this either globally or class based.Thanks [How to hide drop down arrow in IE8 & IE9?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19407332/how-to-hide-drop-down-arrow-in-ie9/19408178#19408178) @spudley

Answer (score 1):

use these styling element

```
select {
    -moz-appearance: none;
    text-indent: 0.01px;
    text-overflow: "";
}
```

Comment: thanks, I eventually found this, but that dint fix anything in IE