# How to hide/remove select default arrow for custom arrow

Tags: jquery, html, css

I would like to know how do I remove or hide the default arrow on my select dropdown.

I do not wish to use javascript/jquery for this, and I dont mind how it degrades in earlier versions of IE either, but I dont know why its not being hidden/removed at all.

FYI: I am using an online source for the custom arrow for example purposes here.

Any help will be appreciated. thanks.

```css
/* -- Styled Selects - wrapped due to FF appearance bug & MSIE -- */

.styled_select {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: auto;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  -o-border-radius: 4px;
  -khtml-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  -o-box-shadow: none;
  -khtml-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}
.styled_select.match-width {
  display: inline-block;
  *display: inline;
  zoom: 1;
}
.styled_select {} .styled_select select {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 9px 32px 9px 12px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  color: #666666;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-style: normal;
  border: none;
  background: transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
  -moz-appearance: window;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -ms-appearance: none;
  -o-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  outline: none;
  z-index: 2;
}
.styled_select select::-ms-expand {
  display: none;
  z-index: -999999;
}
.styled_select:hover {
  border: 1px solid #00adf1;
}
.styled_select:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 32px;
  height: 100%;
  speak: none;
  content: '';
  z-index: 1;
}
.styled_select:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: -8px 0 0 -4px;
  background: url(https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/slim-square-icons-basics/100/basics-08-128.png) no-repeat 50% 60%;
  speak: none;
  content: '';
}
.ie8 .styled_select select,
.ie9 .styled_select select {
  padding-right: 12px;
}
.ie8 .styled_select:after,
.ie9 .styled_select:after,
.ie8 .styled_select:before,
.ie9 .styled_select:before {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<span class="styled_select">
          <select>
                <option value="">Select One</option>
                <option value="1">Option 01</option>
                <option value="2">Option 02</option>
          </select>
</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about hiding the native arrow in IE8 then it's not possible. In IE9 you can just simply cover it up as outlined here: [How to hide drop down arrow in IE8 & IE9?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19407332/how-to-hide-drop-down-arrow-in-ie8-ie9).

On more modern browsers:

```
-moz-appearance: none;
-webkit-appearance: none;
-ms-appearance: none;
-o-appearance: none;
appearance: none;
```

should work just fine, but only for the browsers that support it: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-appearance

However, as others have noted, you have a custom arrow in the pseudo element `::before`. If you're talking about this arrow then just remove said pseudo element.

Comment: I want my custom arrow, not the default arrow

Comment: @Krystyna, in which browsers are you still seeing the default arrow?

Comment: @Krystyna Can you try changing `-moz-appearance: window;` to `-moz-appearance: none;`? Though that being said, `-moz-appearance: window;` seems to be working fine in Firefox 46.0.1 with hiding the arrow.

Comment: Yes, I changed that and now it works in firefox, however in IE9 how do I degrade it? in IE9 at the moment it has the default sitting on top of the custom arrow

Comment: As noted in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19407332/how-to-hide-drop-down-arrow-in-ie8-ie9, the only way to hide it in IE9 is to cover it up. But with that comes bad usability as you can no longer trigger the dropdown by clicking on the arrow since it's on drop of the select.

Comment: hmm, right, okay. I really dont want to have to resort to jquery for customizing the select, but I dont see any other option..

Answer (score 0):

It's the `::before` pseudo element. Just remove it from your CSS:

```
.styled_select:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: -8px 0 0 -4px;
  background: url(https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/slim-square-icons-basics/100/basics-08-128.png) no-repeat 50% 60%;
  speak: none;
  content: '';
}
```

```css
/* -- Styled Selects - wrapped due to FF appearance bug & MSIE -- */

.styled_select {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: auto;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  -o-border-radius: 4px;
  -khtml-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  -o-box-shadow: none;
  -khtml-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}
.styled_select.match-width {
  display: inline-block;
  *display: inline;
  zoom: 1;
}
.styled_select {} .styled_select select {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 9px 32px 9px 12px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  color: #666666;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-style: normal;
  border: none;
  background: transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
  -moz-appearance: window;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -ms-appearance: none;
  -o-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  outline: none;
  z-index: 2;
}
.styled_select select::-ms-expand {
  display: none;
  z-index: -999999;
}
.styled_select:hover {
  border: 1px solid #00adf1;
}
.styled_select:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 32px;
  height: 100%;
  speak: none;
  content: '';
  z-index: 1;
}
.ie8 .styled_select select,
.ie9 .styled_select select {
  padding-right: 12px;
}
.ie8 .styled_select:after,
.ie9 .styled_select:after,
.ie8 .styled_select:before,
.ie9 .styled_select:before {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<span class="styled_select">
          <select>
                <option value="">Select One</option>
                <option value="1">Option 01</option>
                <option value="2">Option 02</option>
          </select>
</span>
```

Comment: @Krystyna  just delete the above CSS rule from your code and arrow will be gone.

Comment: I removed the `:before` pseudo element, is this what you meant? If so, it removes the entire select box, nothing is there...

Comment: @Krystyna no it doesn't. See the demo in answer. You probably messed up something else.

Comment: err, I meant removing the default arrow, not my custom arrow

Comment: @Krystyna I don't see any default arrow..! Maybe you should specify the browser version etc you're using..!

Answer (score 0):

Makes the dropdown width exceed it's wrapper width.. And add overflow hidden to the dropdown wrapper..
Example:

```
.dropdown {
width: 220px;
}
.dropdown-wrapper {
width: 200px;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: I dont like this, because I want the width of the dropdown list to be the same as the select box