# Stylize select drop down tag

Tags: html, css

I'm styling a select tag and I wonder if i can take the space on the right, where are the arrows

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Pqwpdm

```
<header class="navbar">
  <div class="navbar__container">
    <select class="navbar__select">
      <option class="navbar__option">Janeiro, 2015</option>
      <option class="navbar__option">Fevereiro, 2015</option>
      <option class="navbar__option">Março, 2015</option>
      <option class="navbar__option">Abril, 2015</option>
      <option class="navbar__option">Maio, 2015</option>
      <option class="navbar__option">Junho, 2015</option>
      <option class="navbar__option">Julho, 2015</option>
      <option class="navbar__option">Agosto, 2015</option>
      <option class="navbar__option">Setembro, 2015</option>
      <option class="navbar__option">Outubro, 2015</option>
      <option class="navbar__option">Novembro, 2015</option>
      <option class="navbar__option">Dezembro, 2015</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</header>


.navbar__select {
  float: right;
  background: #C9D3DD;
  font-size: 17px;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

Thanks! :).

Comment: What do you mean by space on the right?  depending on your operating systtem you'll get a different view of the select box.

Comment: there is a space in the right that i can't take off because the arrows of the select are there.. i want take off..

Comment: It depends what browser you are using. `-webkit-appearance` will only work in chrome and safari.  What if you add the following 2 properties: `appearance:none;
-moz-appearance:none; /* Firefox */`

Comment: well there is another way apply this: to all your option tag: `<option [some attributes><pre>>    [some text]</pre></option>`

Comment: You know what you are having and trying to do is very much against the accessibility, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question [has already been asked.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16603979/select-removing-dropdown-arrow)

To recap:

- Use `-moz-appearance: none` to disable the dropdown arrow in Firefox
- Use `-webkit-appearance: none` to disable the dropdown arrow in Webkit browsers (such as Google Chrome)
- Set `display: none` on the psudo class available for the dropdown arrow in Internet Explorer: `::-ms-expand`

Comment: That space is there only because the select box is larger than the text within. If you want to change the width of the select box, you can by putting `width: __px;` in the CSS for it.