# How to hide default select drop down arrow in IE 11 without enabling x-ua-compatible meta tag

Tags: html, css, select, internet-explorer-11, dropdown

Using the `-ms-expand pseudo-element`, I am able to hide the drop down arrow in `IE11`.

When the `HTML` was opened directly in IE it worked fine.
When the same `HTML` deployed in web server, the drop down arrow was turned on.

Adding the below meta tag to the page hides the drop down arrow both in local and in server.

```
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=11,10,9">
```

But this tag has to be added to the top most webpage, which will get applied to all the web pages through out the application. This affects the `JavaScrip`t functions at so many places which requires a lot of change and regression testing.

Is there a way we can make `-ms-expand` to work without enabling x-ua-compatible?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select removing dropdown arrow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16603979/select-removing-dropdown-arrow)