# Custom select with long select content

Tags: html, css

Hello I am having a bit of issue regarding my custom select lay-out. I created a custom select that works within all browsers, even IE. But I have a problem with my custom select. First have a look at my HTML code:

```css
.select-style {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 120px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #fff;
  background: #fff;
  position: relative;
}
.select-style:after {
  top: 50%;
  left: 85%;
  border: solid transparent;
  content: " ";
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  border-top-color: #000000;
  border-width: 5px;
  margin-top: -2px;
  z-index: 100;
}
.select-style select {
  padding: 5px 8px;
  width: 130%;
  border: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  background-image: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
}
.select-style select:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="select-style">
  <select>
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    <option value="Volkswagon Polo">Volkswagon Polo</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

**The lay-out problem**

If you select the "Volkswagon Polo" option you see that the text is behind the black arrow. Which looks not very nice. I tried several options but I could not manage it to make it look nice. I tried to use the `text-overflow` option but without succes. Does anyone knows a nice way to not show the text through the arrow icon, without changing the width of the select?

Comment: Hi, is it okey if we remove drop down arrow after select?

Comment: If you manage to make it look the same and it works also in all the other browser, especially in IE, then I am fine by removing the after select property. @Manoj

Comment: Hope this will serve your purpose http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16603979/select-removing-dropdown-arrow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made some improvements. Your arrow want respected by your padding and the select was able get bigger than the wrapper, fixed that with `overflow: hidden; width: 100%;`:

```css
.select-style {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    width: 130px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #fff;
    background: #fff;
    position: relative;
}

.select-style:after {
    top: 50%;
    right: 10px;
    border: solid transparent;
    content: " ";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
    border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border-top-color: #000000;
    border-width: 5px;
    margin-top: -2px;
    z-index: 100;
}

.select-style select {
    padding: 5px 28px 5px 8px;
    border: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    background-color: transparent;
    background-image: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
}

.select-style select:focus {
    outline: none;
}

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="select-style">
    <select>
        <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
        <option value="saab">Saab</option>
        <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
        <option value="audi">Audi</option>
        <option value="Volkswagon Polo">Volkswagon Polo</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x64Lcpbp/5/)**

By floating your `.select-style` and removing your width you can make it adjust automatically to its contents.

Comment: Yep, that is what I am looking for. Perfect solution. Thank you! :)

Comment: But it might not work for IE 10 " -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;"

Comment: @Manoj [`appearance`](http://caniuse.com/#search=appearance) has some weird support behavior. Thanks for noting! Might look like a default select bordered and a arrow on top. Should be functional in any case though.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
.select-style {
   padding: 0 20px 0 0;
   margin: 0;
   border: 1px solid #ccc;
   width: auto;
   border-radius: 3px;
   overflow: hidden;
   background-color: #fff;
   background: #fff;
   position: relative;
   display: inline-block;}
```

It's because you set .select-style width to fixed value. 
display: inline-block; prevent element from expanding to full width, padding set some space near arrow. And now it looks nice :).

I also noticed, taht when I removed width from .select-style select and add text-align:center it looks even beter :).

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to change the width you can use

```
    .select-style select {
    /*for firefox*/
    -moz-appearance: none;
    /*for chrome*/
    -webkit-appearance:none;
  }

  /*for IE10*/
 .select-style select::-ms-expand {
   display: none;
 }
```

This will remove drop down arrow

Comment: yes! I am aware of that but what I wanted is to have an custom arrow. Anyways thanks for your answer,.

Comment: custom arrow will be there before you select, it will dis appear once you select from drop down