# Remove the arrow that appears for input type="time" for HTML5

Tags: javascript, css, html, input, time

I am using the default HTML5 
sample line of code:

I have used a custom background. I want to remove the black arrow that appears on the right.

[The image shows a black arrow that appears. Need it remove it. I tried many css tricks but didn't work.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3I8fn.jpg)

Sample code

Comment: Show the HTML structure could be a good start

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select removing dropdown arrow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16603979/select-removing-dropdown-arrow)

Comment: As you edit your post, please remove "Hello Guys", and  "Any help appreciated"

Answer (score 10):

```
input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button, 
input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button { 
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    margin: 0; 
}
```

or

```
/* Hide the cancel button */
::-webkit-search-cancel-button { 
    -webkit-appearance: none; 
}

/* Hide the magnifying glass */
::-webkit-search-results-button {
     -webkit-appearance: none; 
}

/* Remove the rounded corners */
input[type=search] { 
    -webkit-appearance: none; 
}
```

Comment: Also add some explanation about the snippet you posted

Comment: I tried the above code. It did not work. Let me put some more info here

Comment: <input type="time" name="timepicker" value="" class="time_element" id="TimerHours" >

Comment: .time_element{
    /*
    background: url(../images/timeBoxBg.png);
    */
    /*
    background-size:60px 30px;
    */
    background-size: 97% 35px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width:99%;
    height:35px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 1px;
}

Answer (score 2):

Arrows

```
input[type="time"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

Clear (x) button

```
input[type="time"]::-webkit-clear-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

##### Just Hide that Arrow

The arrow for `<input type="time">` itself — which for example appears on Android — can be removed like this:

```
input[type="time"] {
  -webkit-appearance: none; // Hide the down arrow
}
```

##### Take Full Control

But hiding the arrow will still leave you with an issue: the input renders a blank space on the right side of the input field, and it won't react to different settings of `text-align`. In order to control these, you need to make further adjustments:

```
input[type="time"] {
  -webkit-appearance: none; // Hide the down arrow
}

// Android renders the time input as a flex box
// with a left-aligned flex element "webkit-date-and-time-value" for the value.
// It also leaves a blank space of 24px for the down arrow.
input[type="time"]::-webkit-date-and-time-value {
  margin: 0; // By default Android renders this as 1px 24px 1px 1px
  width: 100%; // Let the flex element take the full width of the input
  text-align: center; // Control your text alignment here
}
```