# Added style to Select element, but now have double toggle button

Tags: html, css

I have added css styling to my select elements. However, as you can see below the element now has a white toggle button and a black one. How can I get rid of the black one?

[image]

```css
.styled-select {
  background: url(http://i62.tinypic.com/15xvbd5.png) no-repeat 96% 0;
  height: 29px;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 240px;
}

.semi-square {
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<select class="styled-select yellow semi-square" (change)="getLocations()" id="interest">

  <option value="default">Select your interest</option>

  <option value="movie_theater">Movie Theaters</option>

  <option value="movie_rental">Movie Rental</option>

</select> within

<select class="styled-select yellow semi-square" (change)="getLocations()" id="distance">

  <option value="2500" selected>2,5</option>

  <option value="5000">5 </option>

  <option value="10000">10</option>

  <option value="20000">20</option>

</select> kilometers <br />
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select removing dropdown arrow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16603979/select-removing-dropdown-arrow)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add     **`-webkit-appearance: none;`** to `select`

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16603979/select-removing-dropdown-arrow)

```css
.styled-select {
      background: url(http://i62.tinypic.com/15xvbd5.png) no-repeat 96% 0;
      height: 29px;
      overflow: hidden;
      width: 240px;
      -webkit-appearance: none;
      -moz-appearance: none;
  }

  .semi-square {
      -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
      -moz-border-radius: 5px;
      border-radius: 5px;
  }
```

```html
<select class="styled-select yellow semi-square" (change)="getLocations()" id="interest">

    <option value="default">Select your interest</option>

    <option value="movie_theater">Movie Theaters</option>

    <option value="movie_rental">Movie Rental</option>

</select> within

<select class="styled-select yellow semi-square" (change)="getLocations()" id="distance">

    <option value="2500" selected>2,5</option>

    <option value="5000">5 </option>

    <option value="10000">10</option>

    <option value="20000">20</option>

</select> kilometers <br />
```