# How to remove arrows of year from ngb datepicker

Tags: angular, ngb-datepicker

When I use ngb-datepicker, I set [minDate] and [maxDate] for one year. So users can only choose a date within one year. But I want to remove the arrows that show beside the year-picker-box. Is it possible to remove them?

My code:

```html
<ngb-datepicker #dp [(ngModel)]="toModel" [minDate]="fromModel" (ngModelChange)="setToDate($event)" [maxDate]="{year: 2019, month: 12, day: 31}" [startDate]="startDate"></ngb-datepicker>
```

[image]

Comment: add the code you tried

Comment: Right and left arrows are html elements and you can find selector and add to it `display: none`. Top and bottom arrows most likely are native browser dropdown  arrows. [Read that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16603979/how-to-remove-the-default-arrow-icon-from-a-dropdown-list-select-element) for info how to remove them.

Comment: `code`<ngb-datepicker #dp [(ngModel)]="toModel" [minDate]="fromModel"
                        (ngModelChange)="setToDate($event)"
                          [maxDate]="{year: 2019, month: 12, day: 31}" [startDate]="startDate"></ngb-datepicker>`code` I set minimum date from component and maximum date from view. That give me one year range. But I see arrows of year picker.

Comment: @Arseniy-II how to get selector for ngb-datepicker. I have no idea for this. Can you show me example. Thank you.

Comment: @AungPhyoOo at the end it is just html and css. Go to your developer tools check what class has that element. Target that element and add `display: none` for that element in your css file

Comment: `.ngb-dp-arrow.right { display: none }`

Comment: It works when I change in developer tools. But not work in my project code. Anyway Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @AungPhyoOo Do you just want the arrows removed, or for the selection to be disabled?

Comment: @IraklisGkougkousis I want to remove just the arrows because I have done disabling them.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the right arrow can be hidden using the following class

```
.custom-select {
background: #ffffff !important;
}

.ngb-dp-arrow.right {
display: none !important;
}
```

Include these classes in styles.css then only it will work, including in styles of a component will be overridden by global css. Also, the class custom-select will hide the arrow of both month and year.