# Proper way to specify css empty url()

Tags: css, url, background-image, inline-styles

I have the following line

```
<select style="appearance:none;background-image:url('');" disabled>...</select>
```

to erase the right "down arrow" of the select box so that it looks like a disabled text box but has the select-option functionality which is manipulated via javascript.

This comes from one of the answers in this post: [How to remove the default arrow icon from a dropdown list (select element)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16603979/how-to-remove-the-default-arrow-icon-from-a-dropdown-list-select-element) and it is the only answer that works for me (I need it to be inline and not requiring additional library).

However in PHPStorm, it shows an error `cannot resolve file ''` which makes me think this is not the proper way to specify an empty image via `url()`.

I have tried this

```
appearance:none;background-image:url('data:')
```

which indeed eliminates the PHPSTorm error and works but it does not "look right" either. I would like to know the proper way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have you tried the following?

```
<select style="appearance:none;background-image: none;" disabled>...</select>
```

Comment: Yes it works! I should have come up with that myself...thank you so much.