# How to remove the HTML select tag's default arrow?

Tags: html, css, vue.js, drop-down-menu, tailwind-css

I am using vuejs and tailwindcss.
How do I remove the default arrow from HTML select's element?
I've already tried removing appearance with css:

```
select {
    -moz-appearance: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -ms-appearance: none;
    -o-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
}
```

as well as with tailwind's `appearance-none`

```
<select :onchange="selectChanged()"
            class="bg-transparent text-xl border-0 rounded-md hover:bg-slate-800 appearance-none" ref=" eventSelect">
```

My current template code:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <select :onchange="selectChanged()"
            class="bg-transparent text-xl border-0 rounded-md hover:bg-slate-800 appearance-none" ref=" eventSelect">
            <option class="bg-slate-800">50m </option>
            <option class="bg-slate-800"> 60m </option>
            <option class="bg-slate-800"> 100m </option>
            <option class="bg-slate-800"> 300m </option>
        </select>
    </div>
</template>
```

It looks like this:

[image: Select HTML eaxmple]

I just can't seem to get it removed for some reason :(

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove the default arrow icon from a dropdown list (select element)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16603979/how-to-remove-the-default-arrow-icon-from-a-dropdown-list-select-element)

Comment: Unfortunately not

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After couple of weeks I found something that have worked for me...
For some reason (probably vuejs default settings) the `<select>` element is styled with background image that contains an arrow. If you remove it, you are still left with default padding, so to reset those two values, I added this:

```
<style>

select {
background: none;
padding: 0;
}

</style>
```

Comment: I tried changing the background color and saw it changing, without the arrow being removed so I thought the arrow and background don't have connection. But apparently changing background color does not affect background image. Removing only `background-image` will also work.

Comment: Amazing, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```css
.custom-select {
  /* Hide the default arrow */
  appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
}
```

```html
<select class="custom-select">
  <option value="option1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
  <option value="option3">Option 3</option>
</select>
```

as you can see the following line of code works as expected, I guess you need to make sure that your CSS is working properly and your styles are applied to your HTML

Comment: I did the same thing and added `background-color:red;` just to check that it applies. It does. Just for some reason the arrow does not remove. That's why I asked the question because I don't know if It's a css problem but maybe more of a vuejs problem...

Comment: if you can share more details maybe I can help you with this issue