# CSS inline svg background in select with firefox

Tags: css, firefox, svg, webkit

I am building a custom select tag with an inline svg background using -webkit-appearance: none in my css.

http://jsfiddle.net/sucrenoir/yHR53/5/

```
select {
    font-size: 30px;
    border: 1px solid lightblue;
    border-radius: 10px;
    color: black;
    padding: 12px;
    width: 300px;
    -webkit-appearance: none;

    background:url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='50px' height='50px'><polyline points='46.139,15.518 25.166,36.49 4.193,15.519'/></svg>") right no-repeat;

    background-color: lightblue;
    background-transparency: 0.5;
    background-position: right 15px top 22px;
    background-size: 18px 18px;
}
```

It does not work in firefox (obviously).

What is the equivalent of -webkit-appearance: none in firefox to get it to work ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: -moz-appearance: none should do it... will test.

Comment: …But it works already in my firefox (= same result as in webkit) without -moz-appearance?

Comment: it does not work in firefox 22. I still haver the firefox arrow in front of the svg arrow. http://jsfiddle.net/sucrenoir/yHR53/7/

Comment: I have firefox 23, on os x. And I don't see this arrow...

Comment: That's weird. I tried with FirefoxNightly (24) on osx and i get this : https://dl.dropbox.com/s/zj40n2zjoa0e07t/2013-05-21_at_15.08.43.png

Comment: dunno, cannot repreduce with my nightly, 24...

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately the answer is no at the moment.

According to [MDN doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-moz-appearance), it's not recommended to use it now as it's buggy.

Comment: Yes right. Maybe i should try another solution... and i found another solution : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5912791/how-to-remove-the-arrow-from-a-select-tag-in-firefox

Comment: With text-indent, i get something passable on both browsers. http://jsfiddle.net/sucrenoir/yHR53/11/ Thx :-)

Answer (score 1):

Should use `-moz-appearance: none;` for Firefox to work.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use:

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
    select {
        background: lightblue; 
    }
}
```