# Hiding default select arrow in Firefox 22

Tags: css, firefox

Following this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/17713753/407943

I've tried implementing the same solution but it does not work on my Windows 7 Firefox 22, this is what I get:

[image]

```
select {
    -moz-appearance: window;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    background: #f5f5f5 url("/images/arrow_down.png") right center no-repeat;
    padding-right: 20px;
}
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
.wrapper {
     background: #f5f5f5 url("/images/arrow_down.png") right center no-repeat;
     padding-right: 20px;
  }
}
```

EDIT: here's a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/TGBEZ/1/

Comment: I think you will have to go for a javascript solution...

Comment: @Brewal can you elaborate?

Answer (score 33):

***Update:*** this trick stopped working as of FF 30. No other fix so far. Keep your eyes on the [full gist](https://gist.github.com/joaocunha/6273016) for updates.

---

**How to remove the `<select>` arrow on Firefox**:

`-moz-appearance:none;` doesn't work by itself. You need to add some `text-indent` and `text-overflow`. Like this:

```
select {
    -moz-appearance: none;
    text-indent: 0.01px;
    text-overflow: '';
}
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/joaocunha/RUEbp/1/

Learn the details on this gist: https://gist.github.com/joaocunha/6273016

Comment: This man needs a medal and this answer 500 upvotes. Only working solution I found on the internet in over an hour.

Comment: But it doesn't work in FF on Android. Use text-indent: 5px to fix it

Comment: @EAndreyF:

"Firefox for Android needs the whole width of the arrow as text-indent. It means you need to set it to at least 5px, but take care since Firefox seems to double the text-indent value on <select> elements."

 - https://gist.github.com/joaocunha/6273016

Comment: sorry to say but its not hide in my firefox version 30.0. please let me know any solution if you have ?

Answer (score 1):

This is a known bug of firefox which won't be corrected soon, or maybe even later (see this [bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=649849)).

There is a pure CSS/HTML workaround :

HTML :

```
<div class="styled">
    <select></select>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
div.styled {
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

div.styled select {
    width: 115%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    background-image: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    border: none;
}
```

**[The Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dSmVR/1/)**

The problem here is that you will have to make sure the text won't be too large, otherwise it will get over the image.

Also, there are javascript solutions. Take a look at [customselect](http://adam.co/lab/jquery/customselect/), a jQuery plugin to easily create your own selects.

Another famous plugin : [chosen](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/)

Answer (score 0):

This is the only solution that really worked for me on FF/IE/Chrome:

[Customized select dropdown arrow not clickable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17811998/customized-select-dropdown-arrow-not-clickable)

Answer (score 0):

Using -moz-appearance: window instead of none seems to be working now in FF 30

Answer (score 0):

I have this working in Firefox 30+ with:

-moz-appearance: textfield;