# Drop Down arrow won't go away in mozilla or ie

Tags: javascript, asp.net, css

I have developed a website in asp.net and i have four drop down lists that are connected to an access database. The thing is when I view in firefox or ie there is a default drop down arrow which i don't want, but if I view in chrome it is not there. I have tried adding these to my style class:

```
 -moz-appearance: none; opacity:0; overflow:hidden; width:120%
```

as well as

```
 -moz-appearance: button; overflow:hidden; width:120%; opacity: 0
```

and I have had no success, and I am well, stuck. any help is greatly appreciated

here is my dropdown list:

```
<asp:DropDownList id="DropDownList3" 
                        runat="server" 
                        AutoPostBack="True" 
                        DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
                        DataTextField="Plant" 
                        DataValueField="Plant" 
                        min-width="156px"
                        width="120%";
                        Font-Bold="true" 
                        Font-Size="x-Large" 
                        style="margin-left: 250px; margin-top:-44.5px;
                        margin-bottom:-20px; 
                        background-color: #FFFFFF; box-shadow:none; 
                        outline-color: #FFFFFF;
                       -moz-appearance: none;
                        overflow:hidden; appearance: none; 
                       -webkit-appearance:none;
                        border: none;
                       text-align: right;" 
                        Enabled="False">
                </asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5912791/how-to-remove-the-arrow-from-a-select-tag-in-firefox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple placing dropdown into a container DIV of a lesser width with `overflow:hidden` should do the trick, for example:

```
<div style="width:200px; overflow:hidden" >
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" style="width:220px">
    </asp:DropDownList>
</div>
```

Comment: This unfortunately did not work for me as the values of the list were no longer displayed

Comment: What do you mean no longer displayed? This approach shouldn't really affect the dropdown list at at all, worst case - cut off some text in the control itself

Comment: Here's jfiddle with the example (dropdown reders as SELECT): http://jsfiddle.net/zD2xF/

Comment: Well when I do it I no longer displays the drop down values

Comment: Can you copy rendered HTML for your dropdown (including container) and paste it into jfiddle?

Comment: Small update: Removed margin styles and restored missing overflow: hidden in the DIV: http://jsfiddle.net/Lwudc/3/ is this the intended behavior?

Comment: Yes but I need those margins as those were the precise location I wanted them on the page

Comment: You can apply the margins to the DIV: http://jsfiddle.net/Lwudc/4/ in this example I left only `margin-left` because negative `margin-top` would take it outside of the page. It should work with other elements present above div

Comment: Here is jFiddle with all your margins applied to the container DIV: http://jsfiddle.net/Lwudc/5/

Answer (score 0):

Try assiging the CSS `display:none;` value

```
style="margin-left: 250px; margin-top:-44.5px;
                        margin-bottom:-20px; 
                        background-color: #FFFFFF; box-shadow:none; 
                        outline-color: #FFFFFF;
                       -moz-appearance: none;
                        overflow:hidden; appearance: none; 
                       -webkit-appearance:none;
                        border: none;
                       text-align: right;
                       display: none;"
```

Comment: This unfortunately did not work for as it did the values were no longer displayed

Answer (score 0):

Setting the following should do the job in mozilla.

```
text-indent:10px;
```

This property will push the default dropbox button under the select area.

Comment: this worked on firefox but it did not have the same effect on ie