# Remove select arrow in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I removed the drop down arrow from a select element using a method found here on SO
[How to remove the arrow from a select element in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5912791/how-to-remove-the-arrow-from-a-select-tag-in-firefox)
 but I still need a solution for IE. Any advice?
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j9LFS/3/)
HTML:

```
<div class="select-wrap">
  <select class="input-country" name="country">
    <option value="">-Select Country-*</option>
    <option value="US" selected="selected">USA</option>
    <option value="AF">AFGHANISTAN</option>
    <option value="AL">ALBANIA</option>
  </select>
<div>
```

CSS:

```
.select-wrap {
width: 340px;
height: 40px;

border: 1px solid black;
}
select {
width: 340px;
height: 100%;
margin: auto 0;
padding-bottom: 4px;
border: none;
-webkit-appearance: none;
-moz-appearance: none;
appearance: none;
text-indent: 0.01px;
text-overflow: ''; 
}
```

I would appreciate a CSS-only solution.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
select::-ms-expand {
display: none;
}
```

Note that this works on IE10+

Comment: Doesn't work for me. http://jsfiddle.net/j9LFS/5/