# dropdown list arrow icon not working properly on IE

Tags: html, asp.net, css, html.dropdownlistfor

Dropdownlist arrow icon not working properly on iE but other browser is working properly.

**CSS:**

```
.custom-dropdown .option {
        line-height: 2em !important;

    }
```

**html:**

```
<select name="name" class="custom-dropdown" id="ddlSecurityFirstQuest" >
<option value="2">What is your pet''s name?</option>
<option value="3">What was the name of your first school?</option>
</select>
```

Attached image here

IE browser dropdownlist arrow working like this

[image]

but i need to IE browser arrrow like this

[image]

Note: Other browser i got like this but IE not working properly

Comment: check to this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5912791/how-to-remove-the-arrow-from-a-select-tag-in-firefox?rq=1

Comment: It is working properly, that is the browser update by IE 11 which is the UI to stand different from the other browser they have deigned that way..!! If you want the dropdown as like that in chrome mention it clearly in the question..! It is better to reframe the question..!!

Answer (score 1):

This problem needs different solutions for different browsers, Use this in your css for IE

```
select::-ms-expand
  display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select {

    margin: 0;
    background-position: 100% center;
    background-clip: border-box;
    background-attachment: scroll;
    background-origin: padding-box;
    background-image: url("../image/common/sleek arrow_black.svg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 8px auto;
    cursor:pointer;
    color:#888;
    border:none;
    outline:none;
    display: inline-block;
    -webkit-appearance:none;
    -moz-appearance:none;
    appearance:none;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```