# Foundation 5 Select boxes style in Firefox

Tags: html, zurb-foundation

I've just upgraded a site to Foundation 5 and noticed that the selects look different in Firefox.  I just double checked, and Foundation's Forms Documentation has the square with little "v", but mine seem to have an extra triangle that's weird, I want just one or the other.  How to fix?

Foundation's documentation, FF and Chrome respectively:
[image]
[image]

Mine in FF:
[image]
Mine in Chrome:
[image]

My code:

```
<form id="frm" name="frm" action="add" method="post" >
```

And:

```
<div class='small-2 large-2 columns'><select id='dept_1' name='dept_1' style='font-size:75%;' class='medium'><option value='0' selected>Choose...</option><option value='5' >Blah</option></select></div>
```

Comment: Found this and it's genius!!!

[Previous question about ugly FF arrow][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5912791/how-to-remove-the-arrow-from-a-select-tag-in-firefox

Comment: Is it really expected behaviour that in a clean Foundation 5.2.3 installation in a Rails App I have to use a hack like
<pre>
select
  -moz-appearance: none
  text-indent: 0.01px
  text-overflow: ''
</pre>
to make the Selectdropdowns look nice ??!!

Comment: @YoLudke It's obviously not optimal, but at least it works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best answer was [How to Remove the Arrow From a Select Tag in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5912791/how-to-remove-the-arrow-from-a-select-tag-in-firefox)