# How can I hide a <select> arrow in Firefox 30+?

Tags: css, firefox

This hack used to work in <= Firefox 29 to remove a `<select>` arrow:

```
text-overflow: '';
text-indent: 0.01px;
-moz-appearance: none;
```

It no longer works in Firefox 30. Arrow is back.

- [Codepen for hack that works in Firefox 29](http://codepen.io/joaocunha/pen/qLgCG)
- [Related bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=649849) (now fixed in Fx 35b)

**Does anyone know a way to achieve the same effect?**

*Note1: I'm not interested in solutions that overlay the arrow with another element, or solutions that nest the select element and do a overflow:hidden.*

*Note2: I tried all `-moz-appearance` possibilities. They either add default styling I cannot override, don't allow custom styling (border and background, specifically), or the arrow is still visible.*

**Update**: it works again in Firefox 35 (currently in beta) using `-moz-appearance: none`, making this look consistent in all latest browsers (Tested in IE11, Firefox 35b, Chrome 39, Safari 8): http://jsfiddle.net/phd5pu9x/

Comment: how about just `appearance:none;` without the moz prefix

Comment: As @Pete suggested, try the **appearance** property. Firefox has been using a Mozilla workaround **-moz-appearance** (and **-webkit-appearance** for some other browsers), so maybe appearance is now properly supported (worth a try). Update: did you do a Ctrl+F5 to refresh your CSS files?

Comment: [Some interesting options here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5912791/how-to-remove-the-arrow-from-a-select-tag-in-firefox)

Comment: @Pete: I tried them all, without success.

Comment: Answered this here without realizing it was a duplicate. Apologies. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23920990/firefox-30-is-not-hiding-select-box-arrows-anymore

Comment: You could use one of the approaches which I explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13968900/703717)

Comment: @Danield Both approaches require extra markup, so I'm not interested in the solution (See my first note). The author claims approach #2 does not require extra markup, but that is not correct, because `::after` does not work on a `<select>`.

Comment: `-moz-appearance: none` works again in Fx 35b.

Comment: `-moz-appearance: window;` works for me.

Answer (score 4):

I fixed my this issue by giving some style to div and select individually.

Anyone can change his width and other style properties a/c to needs. :)

Here is the js fiddle for it. [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mzbv7/108/)

```
<div  class="common-dropdown-small-div" style="width: 220px">
<select id="select" class="common-dropdown-project-select">
    <option>
        apple
    </option>
    <option>
        blackberry
    </option>
    <option>
       pumpkin
    </option>
</select>
```

```
.common-dropdown-small-div{
border: 1px solid rgb(208, 208, 208);
overflow: hidden; 
width: 220px;  }

.common-dropdown-project-select{
  width: 100% !important;
background-image: url("http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/f/f1/Down_Arrow_Icon.png");
background-position: 97% 60%, 0 0 ! important;    
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: 25px 16px;
border: none  ! important;    
outline : medium none !important;
display: inline-flex !important;
height: 33px !important;
vertical-align: top;
-webkit-appearance: none; }

select::-ms-expand {
display: none;}
```

Comment: may be, we dont use IE 9.

Comment: it used to work 4 years ago, after new update, things change

Answer (score 2):

Put the select in another container which has `overflow: hidden;`, make the select wider than the container. If you want a border, add it to the container.

An example is the select at the bottom of this page:
https://mozillians.org/en-US/

Comment: This approach doesn't work (if I am not missing something) when you do not know in advance how long the options will be. The code snippet in the question allowed for a fixed-size select box with a drop-down box that adjusted its width automatically to the longest option.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this solution for firefox, using vendor pseudo class :-moz-any() and pointer events only for mozilla and do not affect other browsers, because both is valid since version 3.6.

here is a jsbin example http://jsbin.com/pozomu/4/edit

Answer (score 0):

/* For mozilla Firefox 30.0+ I used the following to coverup the reappearing arrow: */

@-moz-document url-prefix() {

```
.yourClass:after {
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: -25px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    content: url('../images/pathToYourDownArrowImage.svg');
    pointer-events: none;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

/* I still use this to move the text over */

```
.yourClass select {
    text-overflow: '';
    text-indent: -1px;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    background: none;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Firefox > 29 -moz-appearance:none; working, But have a problem with width, we extend the width of select from 100 to 110% to hide, but it affects the design of a forms, So i just hide it with a div and over come it,

Check the codepen version

http://codepen.io/ssbalakumar/pen/jgLEq

Answer (score -1):

As @mircea c alluded to ...

If your HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="styled-select">
   <select>
     <option>Here is the first option</option>
     <option>The second option</option>
     <option>The thrid option</option>
   </select>
</div>
```

Then you can remove the dropdown arrow in Firefox 30+

```
.styled-select { 
  overflow: hidden; 
  width: 200px;
}

@-moz-document url-prefix(){
  .styled-select select { width: 110%; }
}
```

**Working demo:** [codepen](http://codepen.io/jamesbarnett/pen/JhHjK)

**FYI:** The same technique works in IE 8 & 9, just use a *conditional comment* instead of `@-moz-document url-prefix()`

Comment: To quote myself: "I'm not interested in solutions that overlay the arrow with another element, or solutions that nest the select element and do a overflow:hidden."