# Firefox 30 is not hiding select box arrows anymore

Tags: html, css, firefox

I have always used the "trick":

```
select {
    -moz-appearance: none;
    text-indent: 0.01px;
    text-overflow: '';
}
```

to do custom select boxes on FF but since version 30 is released this stopped working completely. I have tried to find if this was deprecated but couldn't find anything. Is there a workaround, or another method to replace this?

Comment: I don't think you should depend on vendor-specific definitions. And what about other browsers? If you want to style the select perhaps a jQuery plugin like Select2 is in order?

Comment: On other browsers this works fine, it was also working fine on FF until version 30

Comment: @AndyM this was obviously changed, deprecated, something. My question would be if someone knows what it should be used now in replacement of that

Comment: I'm going to look into it. I think it might be related to a bug that went through divorcing the arrow from padding, as odd as that sounds. I'll post an update when I figure something out.

Comment: [Duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23680116/how-can-i-hide-a-select-arrow-in-firefox-30)

Comment: Thanks for taking a look @AndyM

Answer (score 26, accepted):

#### Update

As of January 2015, this now works again with the release of Firefox 35. See the answer below for historical reference.

---

---

---

## Background

The hack that was used is this:

```
select {
    -moz-appearance: none;
    text-indent: 0.01px;
    text-overflow: '';
}
```

In my testing, on FF 29, `-moz-appearance:none;` had no affect. What caused the arrow box to not appear was the second two lines. It said that any overflow is to be replaced by an empty string, and then it used text-indent to cause the `select` to overflow. Since the arrow box is rendered as a single element, similar to a single letter, this caused it to be replaced by the empty string.

## What Happened

Someone at Mozilla noticed that if you have padding on a dropdown `select`, the arrow doesn't change size. [**According to the bug report**](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=963970), this issue has now been fixed:

[image]

The problem is that this has divorced the arrow from normal CSS rules. I've tried `padding`, `text-indent`, `margin`, `white-space`, `text-wrap`, and a few more, and I can't find anything that will affect it. [**Elsewhere around**](https://gist.github.com/joaocunha/6273016#comment-1222888) [**the internet**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23680116/how-can-i-hide-a-select-arrow-in-firefox-30), people are saying the same thing, unfortunately.

## What Now

1. We have a few options. You can use an overlay combined with `pointer-events:none` to style the dropdown however you want: [**Tutorial**](http://red-team-design.com/making-html-dropdowns-not-suck/)
2. You can create a completely separate dropdown to replace `select`, using Javascript: [**Tutorial**](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/10/04/custom-drop-down-list-styling/)

We can also watch the [**request on Firefox's Bugzilla**](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=649849), and hope that someday they will create a non-hacky way to do this. **PLEASE NOTE**: Don't go there and start posting comments about wanting it. Part of the reason it's been so delayed is that people threw a fit. It may help to [**vote for the issue**](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/page.cgi?id=voting/user.html&bug_id=649849#vote_649849).

---

## Update Sept. 2014

This is now being [**actively worked on**](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=649849#c152) for Firefox. 2 patches have been submitted and have been awaiting review for a week. Most probably scenario is that this makes it into FF35 Aurora, and we have a few weeks for it to get reviewed and approved before the cutoff date (Firefox operates on a 6 week release schedule). It could also be delayed, and it could even theoretically be "uplifted", meaning patched in the current Aurora and Beta versions, to get released sooner.

---

## Update Oct. 2014

This how now been [**officially resolved**](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=649849#c161)! Kind of. A patch to allow users to hide the dropdown arrow element has been committed and will be shipped with [**Firefox 35**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/Releases/35) in January 2015.

This will only allow users to hide the arrow. To style it is another issue, which has been spun off into [**another bug ticket**](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1076846) which will be considered in the future.

---

## Update Jan. 2015

This has now been fixed! [Firefox 35](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/Releases/35) came out on January 13, and you can now use `-moz-appearance:none` to remove the arrow.

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed answer Andy, I will take a look to it and try your suggested solutions. Did you see the date of that bug? I'm aware of people asking for a fix for a LONG time. Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help. Is there anything else that you are wondering about that I can address?

Comment: Hi @AndyM thanks again for your great answer, I have gone through but on both cases the select structure has to be rewritten (adding classes, adding markup before & after etc). The option they took down was working with the regular select element. I will set your answer as correct, because it is and because the effort you put, didn't work in my case only because the form structure is pulled out from a plugin and I cannot edit the elements. When I have time I'll add that markup & parenting tags with jquery. Thanks again.

Comment: When you say both cases, do you mean the two options that I suggested under What Now? I can help you get either of those working if you are interested. Depends a lot on how far back you want to support browser-wise.

Comment: @AndyM the release is tomorrow - get ready to update your answer! https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/Releases/35

Answer (score 7):

Yes ! Is good ! Thks

[JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/wiloud/mzbv7/)

```
.customSelect {
    font-size: inherit;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0.5em;
    background-color: transparent;
    color: #393939;
    opacity:1;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    border: 0 none;
    border-radius: 0px;
    border:1px solid #B1B2B3;
    padding-right: 2.5em;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.SelectBox select {
   background: transparent;
   width: 182px;
   padding-right: 29px;
   font-size: 100%;
   text-indent: 0.01px;
   text-overflow: "";
   border: none;
   height: 17.5px;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
}

.SelectBox {
   width: 154px;
   height: 15.8px;
   overflow: hidden;
   background: url("Images/Arrow.png") no-repeat 141px center #ffffff;
   border-radius:2px;
   border: 1px solid #B90F22;
}

<div class="SelectBox">
   <select>
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
        <option>4</option>
   </select>
</div>
```

This seems to work fine in every major browser but IE. IE is falling back to the default dropdown so that shouldn't be too much of a problem.

Answer (score 1):

The response provide by Mozilla Firefox to this issue is just unacceptable. The browser is broken and is nothing more than an open sore for malicious code.  They promote the V29-30 browser as a security update, but it took over a week since the release date for a notification to appear for V30.

My own response will be to do nothing and I encourage all other developers to do the same. Eventually users will get tired of the design inconsistencies and abandon Mozilla Firefox like they have been in even greater numbers.

If a reasonable support request is meet with sheer contempt and other browsers can do it but Mozilla Firefox no longer can.   It’s not me that has to fix my code, but Mozilla Firefox has to fix theirs!

Answer (score 1):

You can use this solution for firefox, using vendor pseudo class :-moz-any() and pointer events only for mozilla and do not affect other browsers, because both is valid since version 3.6.

here is a jsbin example
http://jsbin.com/pozomu/4/edit

Answer (score 0):

Although it's a quite dirty hack, you can fix this by adding another overlay element above the arrow down in the CSS of your select wrapper (in my case .form-control-select):

```
/* The arrow */
.form-control-select:after {
    content: "\f078";
    z-index: 3;
    pointer-events: none;
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    top: 9px;
    padding: 6px 7px;
    font-size: 10px;
}

/* the white overlay to hide Firefox' arrow */    
.form-control-select:before {
    position: absolute;
    right: 1px;
    top: 2px;
    bottom: 1px;
    width: 20px;
    background: #fff;
    content: "";
    z-index: 2;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
    border-top-right-radius: 1px;
    pointer-events: none; 
}
```

My HTML:

```
<div class="form-control-select">
  <select class="form-control">
    <option value="1">one</option>
    <option value="2">two</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my this issue by giving some style to div and select individually.

Anyone can change his width and other style properties a/c to needs. :)

Here is the js fiddle for it.  [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mzbv7/108/)
tested on all the browsers.

select::-ms-expand for IE and -webkit-user-select: none for chrome.

```
 <div  class="common-dropdown-small-div" style="width: 220px">
    <select id="select" class="common-dropdown-project-select">
        <option>
            apple
        </option>
        <option>
            blackberry
        </option>
        <option>
           pumpkin
        </option>
    </select>
</div>
.common-dropdown-small-div{
  border: 1px solid rgb(208, 208, 208);
  border-radius: 5px !important;
  overflow: hidden; 
}

.common-dropdown-project-select{
  width: 100% !important;
  background-image: url("http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/f/f1/Down_Arrow_Icon.png");
  background-position: 97% 60%, 0 0 ! important;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 25px 16px;
  border: none  ! important;    
  outline : medium none !important;
  display: inline-flex !important;
  height: 33px !important;
  vertical-align: top;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

select::-ms-expand {
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to wrap the `select` elements in container elements with `overflow: hidden`.  Increase the width of the `select` elements to push the down arrow to the right and out of the picture.  Then add a border to the container elements that matches the `select` elements.

```
.select-container {
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 33px;
    border-right: 1px solid #B3B6BD;
}

.select-container select {
    width: 113%;
}
```

The problem is that that this will affect styles set on `focus` or validation errors, which is why I ended up doing what totas suggested and covering the arrows with pseudo-elements.