# select element arrow can be hidden on chrome but not firefox

Tags: css, firefox, select

**Note: This Question is not a duplicate because the answers in the older questions do not work on FireFox 30.00 and up!**
I am using the CSS below to replace the arrow of the select item and it's style. It works on Chrome but on FireFox 30 and above it looks like this:
[image]
Here is my CSS:

```
select { 
-webkit-appearance: none; 
-moz-appearance: none !important; 
appearance: none !important; 
padding: 2px 30px 2px 2px; 
border: none; 
background: transparent url(../images/select.gif) no-repeat left center; 
}
```

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2Q6Fe/)
Can i remove the arrow?

Comment: that answer didn't work you had to check out before marking question as duplicated

Comment: Be explicit about Firefox versions if you can.

Comment: @jqbeginner, See this SO question on your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23680116/how-can-i-hide-a-select-arrow-in-firefox-30

Comment: And this post about it is also helpful:http://www.currelis.com/hiding-select-arrow-firefox-30.html