# How can I format <select>'s <option> element?

Tags: html

How can I format `<select>`'s `<option>` element? Currently we have to use some plugins, like select2, or chosen, or selectboxit, or selectizr.

These js files are big size if we only need to modify UI of `<select>`'s `<option>` element, and don't need to use these libraries other features like, tagging, search etc.

I was able to remove `<select>`'s arrow so I can use any custom arrow or not. check it at : 
[How can I hide a <select> arrow in Firefox 30+?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23680116/how-can-i-hide-a-select-arrow-in-firefox-30)

But I did't find any option for improving presentation of  elements.

Comment: You can't. Only option is to build something that  'looks' like a select box. Native option element cant be styled (Consistently xbrowser)

Comment: Is there a specific thing you want to do? "improve the presentation" is very vague.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/7208786/859640.

Answer (score 0):

About the most you can do is to `color` the text and change the `background-color`.

```html
<select>
    <option style="background-color: red;">Opt 1</option>
    <option style="background-color: green; color: white;">Opt 2</option>
    <option style="background-color: blue; color: white;">Opt 3</option>
</select>
```

You can try applying additional styles, but it's not a standard thing to do.  Some browsers will even ignore styling applied to the `select` and `option` tags.