# Dropdown css in ie not working

Tags: html, css

I have one problem in css dropdown, i want to make both look exactly alike. can someone help me to this.

This was shown in chrome i want to render these styles in all browsers.

[image]

But in ie and safari it look like this.

[image]

Comment: What have you tried and why doesn't it work? For example, what css code are you using to style this?

Comment: I guess you want custom arrow style ..check this link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5912791/how-to-remove-the-arrow-from-a-select-tag-in-firefox

Comment: Share your code and tries, otherwise members maybe will downvote your question

Comment: Sorry guys, these are the css of selectselect {
-webkit-appearance: menulist;
box-sizing: border-box;
align-items: center;
border: 1px solid;
border-image-source: initial;
border-image-slice: initial;
border-image-width: initial;
border-image-outset: initial;
border-image-repeat: initial;
white-space: pre;
-webkit-rtl-ordering: logical;
color: black;
background-color: white;
cursor: default;
}

Comment: It works without any bgimage in chrome but in ie problem occurs. to your reference this is not my design, im just fixing the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your css file you have to add this keywords for support in different browsers

-moz     for mozilla and chrome
-webkit   for safari
-o           for opera
-ms

and i think the the css would work fine with ie 10.0

here's an ex.

`div {
    -webkit-transition: width 2s; /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
    transition: width 2s;
}`

Comment: I don't understand how `transition` comes in this scenario?

Comment: no juz gave an example  for cross browser .i  used transition juz to show the use of webkit. Its not related to the dropdown code but i think the code is facing cross browser issue

Comment: actually OP want custom arrow for select element, As by default select arrow behave differently for every browser.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to add custom arrow for select element you have to wrap the `select` element inside a div and then give `overflow:hidden`. check the **[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/yesupeci/1/edit)**.

```
.custom-select{ 
  width:80px;
  overflow:hidden;
}

select {
   width:100px;
   -webkit-appearance: none;
   -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
   background: url('http://icons.aniboom.com/Energy/Resources/userControls/TimeFrameDropDownFilter/Dropdown_Arrow.png') no-repeat 58px center;
}
```

HTML is like this.

```
<div class="custom-select">
<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
</div>
```