# How to remove all the borders of a selectbox?

Tags: jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

How can I remove the all the borders of the `selectbox` using `css` or `Jquery` ?

My code,

```
<select id="doctor_ch">
   <option value="1" selected>One</option>
   <option value="2">Two</option>
</select>
```

CSS

```
  #doctor_ch{
    background-color: #88AFF2; 
    color:#fff; 
    margin-top: 15px;
 }
```

When I use this code it only changes the arrow style. I want to remove the arrow background too.How can I remove it ?

Current result,

[image]

Expected result,

[image]

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qgwrgzen/)

How can I do this ?

Comment: looks fine in chrome.

Comment: @MilindAnantwar How to do it in firefox ?

Comment: You can't do this reliably cross browser. If you want full control over the style of a select element you would need to use a plugin such as [Select2](https://select2.github.io/examples.html)

Comment: @VinodVT Now you can try to this http://jsfiddle.net/nroxs6gw/

Comment: please see below:

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5912791/how-to-remove-the-arrow-from-a-select-tag-in-firefox][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5912791/how-to-remove-the-arrow-from-a-select-tag-in-firefox

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firefox has some problems with select-background. You can try this code - it'll remove the arrow, and then you can add a background image with your arrow (I took an icon from google search, just put you icon instead)

I get this on FireFox (You can use any arrow icon you want):

[image]

```css
#doctor_ch{
    background: url('http://s4.postimg.org/5yxladijd/icon_sort_down.gif') no-repeat right #88AFF2;
    color:#fff; 
    padding-right:15px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    appearance:none;
    -moz-appearance:none; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-appearance:none; /* Safari and Chrome */
 }
```

```html
<select id="doctor_ch">
    <option value="1" selected>One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but the arrow image is not loaded

Comment: Strange. But anyway it doesn't matter - just replace it with your url. I used an image of a tiny icon from the internet.

Comment: I changed the icon and the URL. Maybe now you'll see it. I use FF and it works great. @VinodVT

Answer (score 1):

Try it

background-color: #88AFF2; 
color:#fff; 
margin-top: 15px;
border:0px;

Answer (score 0):

You change css like this

```css
#doctor_ch{
    background-color: #88AFF2; 
    color:#fff; 
    margin-top: 15px;
    -webkit-appearance:none;
}
```

and add triangle using css for #doctor_ch:after