# How to remove the dropdownlist arrow in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

How can i remove the arrow at dropdownlist show in asp.net,i dont want the arrow because i want use my own image  to create a fancy look for dropdownlist.

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="cboLang" Runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" onselectedindexchanged="cboLang_SelectedIndexChanged" Font-Size="XX-Small" Width="95" Height="26" >
                        <asp:ListItem Value="EN-US">ENGLISH</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="ZH-CN">&#20013;&#25991;</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="TH-TH">&#3616;&#3634;&#3625;&#3634;&#3652;&#3607;&#3618;</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="EN-IE">ti&#7871;ng Vi&#7879;t</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="EN-TT">Korean</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="EN-AU">Indo</asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cant do it with asp.net dropdown controls. 
you can use auto complete textbox at that place.
it is also possible to hide arrow with telerik combo box.

Answer (score 5):

you can add cssClass to your dropdown **cssClass="select"** like :

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="cboLang" Runat="server" cssClass="select" AutoPostBack="True" onselectedindexchanged="cboLang_SelectedIndexChanged" Font-Size="XX-Small" Width="95" Height="26" >
                    <asp:ListItem Value="EN-US">ENGLISH</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="ZH-CN">&#20013;&#25991;</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="TH-TH">&#3616;&#3634;&#3625;&#3634;&#3652;&#3607;&#3618;</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="EN-IE">ti&#7871;ng Vi&#7879;t</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="EN-TT">Korean</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="EN-AU">Indo</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
```

and add the following style to the head tag

```
<style>
.select
{
    border-radius: 5px;
   -webkit-appearance: none;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score -1):

Not possible to change how `<select>` tag is rendered  , you can use any other way to display multiple values as autocomplete textbox

check these links :

[Remove dropdown (select) button from dropdown menus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4273493/remove-dropdown-select-button-from-dropdown-menus)

[Remove drop-down arrow from <select> element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10862050/remove-drop-down-arrow-from-select-element)